# How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, encoding, utf-8

I need to get UTF-8 working in my Java webapp (servlets + JSP, no framework used) to support `äöå` etc. for regular Finnish text and Cyrillic alphabets like `ЦжФ` for special cases.

My setup is the following:

- Development environment: Windows XP
- Production environment: Debian

Database used: MySQL 5.x

Users mainly use Firefox2 but also Opera 9.x, FF3, IE7 and Google Chrome are used to access the site.

How to achieve this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153527/setting-the-character-encoding-in-form-submit-for-internet-explorer

Answer (score 564, accepted):

*Answering myself as the FAQ of this site encourages it. This works for me:*

Mostly characters äåö are not a problematic as the default character set used by browsers and tomcat/java for webapps is latin1 ie. ISO-8859-1 which "understands" those characters.

To get UTF-8 working under Java+Tomcat+Linux/Windows+Mysql requires the following:

### Configuring Tomcat's server.xml

It's necessary to configure that the connector uses UTF-8 to encode url (GET request) parameters:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
 maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
 enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
 connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
 compression="on" 
 compressionMinSize="128" 
 noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
 URIEncoding="UTF-8"
/>
```

The key part being **URIEncoding="UTF-8"** in the above example. This quarantees that Tomcat handles all incoming GET parameters as UTF-8 encoded.
As a result, when the user writes the following to the address bar of the browser:

```
 https://localhost:8443/ID/Users?action=search&name=*ж*
```

the character ж is handled as UTF-8 and is encoded to (usually by the browser before even getting to the server) as **%D0%B6**.

*POST request are not affected by this.*

### CharsetFilter

Then it's time to force the java webapp to handle all requests and responses as UTF-8 encoded. This requires that we define a character set filter like the following:

```
package fi.foo.filters;

import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CharsetFilter implements Filter {

    private String encoding;

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");
        if (encoding == null) encoding = "UTF-8";
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain next)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Respect the client-specified character encoding
        // (see HTTP specification section 3.4.1)
        if (null == request.getCharacterEncoding()) {
            request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        }

        // Set the default response content type and encoding
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        next.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

This filter makes sure that if the browser hasn't set the encoding used in the request, that it's set to UTF-8.

The other thing done by this filter is to set the default response encoding ie. the encoding in which the returned html/whatever is. The alternative is to set the response encoding etc. in each controller of the application.

This filter has to be added to the **web.xml** or the deployment descriptor of the webapp:

```
 <!--CharsetFilter start--> 

  <filter>
    <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>fi.foo.filters.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

The instructions for making this filter are found at the [tomcat wiki (http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Tomcat/UTF-8)](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Tomcat/UTF-8)

### JSP page encoding

In your **web.xml**, add the following:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Alternatively, all JSP-pages of the webapp would need to have the following at the top of them:

```
 <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
```

If some kind of a layout with different JSP-fragments is used, then this is needed in **all** of them.

### HTML-meta tags

JSP page encoding tells the JVM to handle the characters in the JSP page in the correct encoding.
Then it's time to tell the browser in which encoding the html page is:

This is done with the following at the top of each xhtml page produced by the webapp:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fi">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
   ...
```

### JDBC-connection

When using a db, it has to be defined that the connection uses UTF-8 encoding. This is done in **context.xml** or wherever the JDBC connection is defiend as follows:

```
      <Resource name="jdbc/AppDB" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000"
        username="foo"
        password="bar"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/      ID_development?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    />
```

### MySQL database and tables

The used database must use UTF-8 encoding. This is achieved by creating the database with the following:

```
   CREATE DATABASE `ID_development` 
   /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci */;
```

Then, all of the tables need to be in UTF-8 also:

```
   CREATE TABLE  `Users` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(30) collate utf8_swedish_ci default NULL
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

The key part being **CHARSET=utf8**.

### MySQL server configuration

MySQL serveri has to be configured also. Typically this is done in Windows by modifying **my.ini** -file and in Linux by configuring **my.cnf** -file.
In those files it should be defined that all clients connected to the server use utf8 as the default character set and that the default charset used by the server is also utf8.

```
   [client]
   port=3306
   default-character-set=utf8

   [mysql]
   default-character-set=utf8
```

### Mysql procedures and functions

These also need to have the character set defined. For example:

```
   DELIMITER $$

   DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `pathToNode` $$
   CREATE FUNCTION `pathToNode` (ryhma_id INT) RETURNS TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8
   READS SQL DATA
   BEGIN

    DECLARE path VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8;

   SET path = NULL;

   ...

   RETURN path;

   END $$

   DELIMITER ;
```

### GET requests: latin1 and UTF-8

If and when it's defined in tomcat's server.xml that GET request parameters are encoded in UTF-8, the following GET requests are handled properly:

```
   https://localhost:8443/ID/Users?action=search&name=Petteri
   https://localhost:8443/ID/Users?action=search&name=ж
```

Because ASCII-characters are encoded in the same way both with latin1 and UTF-8, the string "Petteri" is handled correctly.

The Cyrillic character ж is not understood at all in latin1. Because Tomcat is instructed to handle request parameters as UTF-8 it encodes that character correctly as **%D0%B6**.

If and when browsers are instructed to read the pages in UTF-8 encoding (with request headers and html meta-tag), at least Firefox 2/3 and other browsers from this period all encode the character themselves as **%D0%B6**.

The end result is that all users with name "Petteri" are found and also all users with the name "ж" are found.

#### But what about äåö?

HTTP-specification defines that by default URLs are encoded as latin1. This results in firefox2, firefox3 etc. encoding the following

```
    https://localhost:8443/ID/Users?action=search&name=*Päivi*
```

in to the encoded version

```
    https://localhost:8443/ID/Users?action=search&name=*P%E4ivi*
```

In latin1 the character **ä** is encoded as **%E4**. *Even though the page/request/everything is defined to use UTF-8*. The UTF-8 encoded version of ä is **%C3%A4**

The result of this is that it's quite impossible for the webapp to correly handle the request parameters from GET requests as some characters are encoded in latin1 and others in UTF-8.
**Notice: POST requests do work as browsers encode all request parameters from forms completely in UTF-8 if the page is defined as being UTF-8**

### Stuff to read

A very big thank you for the writers of the following for giving the answers for my problem:

- http://tagunov.tripod.com/i18n/i18n.html
- http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Tomcat/UTF-8
- http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/HTTPCharset/
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html
- http://cagan327.blogspot.com/2006/05/utf-8-encoding-fix-tomcat-jsp-etc.html
- http://cagan327.blogspot.com/2006/05/utf-8-encoding-fix-for-mysql-tomcat.html
- http://jeppesn.dk/utf-8.html
- http://www.nabble.com/request-parameters-mishandle-utf-8-encoding-td18720039.html
- http://www.utoronto.ca/webdocs/HTMLdocs/NewHTML/iso_table.html
- http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

### Important Note

[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) supports the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) using 3-byte UTF-8 characters. If you need to go outside of that (certain alphabets require more than 3-bytes of UTF-8), then you either need to use a flavor of `VARBINARY` column type or use the [`utf8mb4` character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) (which requires MySQL 5.5.3 or later). Just be aware that using the `utf8` character set in MySQL won't work 100% of the time.

### Tomcat with Apache

One more thing If you are using Apache + Tomcat + mod_JK connector then you also need to do following changes:

1. Add URIEncoding="UTF-8" into tomcat server.xml file for 8009 connector, it is used by mod_JK connector. `<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>`
2. Goto your apache folder i.e. `/etc/httpd/conf` and add `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` in `httpd.conf file`. **Note:** First check that it is exist or not. If exist you may update it with this line. You can add this line at bottom also.

Comment: These steps also work with Struts/tiles and a postgres database.

Comment: Two comments: 1) in **HMTL-meta tags** you included a xml declaration. Remove it, it would only trigger browsers in quirks mode, you don't want to have that. Also, the HTML meta tags are in fact already implicitly done by JSP `pageEncoding`, so you could even leave it away. 2) in **MySQL database and tables** you used `utf8_swedish_si`, this should have been `utf8_unicode_ci`. You could even leave the collation away, just `CHARACTER SET utf8` is enough.

Comment: Neither of the documents I consulted regarding HTML meta tags and quirks mode (e.g. http://www.ericmeyeroncss.com/bonus/render-mode.html, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) indicate that the presence of <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' has any impact on the rendering mode.

Comment: As an interesting side note you may also want to be aware that if you have a listener that accesses a request parameter, you will need to add a listener that sets the charset instead of a filter because the listeners are executed before the filters. I followed all the steps and it still didn't work because of this. Just thought I would pass along this info, in case anyone else has a similar problem.

Comment: Also in mysql server configuration should be added:
[mysqld]
default-character-set=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake

Comment: Since this question is tagged with [tag:MySQL], it's really important that one really understands what "utf-8" means to MySQL. Specifically, the `CHARACTER SET utf8` designation in MySQL can only store characters that are in the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane) and doesn't support "real" UTF-8 but a 3-byte subset thereof. You can read lots more about this [here](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) and [here](http://mzsanford.wordpress.com/2010/12/28/mysql-and-unicode/).

Comment: I tried everything mentioned above but it doesn't work, so I changed the default encoding of JVM  from windows-1250 to UTF-8 and it worked. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @testing123 please let me know what is to be done in order to convert this listener into filter since I'm already having tiles listener.

Comment: @XCoder My comment wasn't about converting the listener to a filter. You just need to add a listener that gets executed first and sets the charset. Let me know if you need more information. Or you can post a link to a new question and I will post some of the code.

Comment: @testing123 thanks for now, it works fine. But I need another help. And here's the link to the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263267/configure-utf-8-with-iis-for-tomcat

Comment: for everyone else trying to use hibernate and still not getting what's wrong - use this kind of connection url  = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gtradedb?characterEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: Note regarding mysql server config, it depends on server version, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405236/jdbc-mysql-utf-8-string-writing-problem

Comment: ## Tomcat with Apache ##
One more thing If you are using Apache + Tomcat + mod_JK connector then you also need to do following changes:

 1. Add URIEncoding="UTF-8" into tomcat server.xml file for 8009 connector, it is used by mod_JK connector. `<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>`
 2. Goto your apache folder i.e. `/etc/httpd/conf` and add `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` in 'httpd.conf' file. **Note:** first check that it is exist or not. If exist you may update it with this line. You can add this line at bottom also.

Comment: Q. How does the browser know what's written in `server.xml`? A. It doesn't. Some of this therefore doesn't make sense. If ISO-8859-1 is the default encoding used by browsers, that's surely what you should specify in `server.xml`?

Comment: If you're writing filenames with unicode in them, you may also want to add the flag -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to the JVM instance. On my Mac, it was unnecessary, but on my Linux box it was necessary.

Comment: This filter must be the first filter in web.xml

Comment: I finally got it working when switching from MyISAM to InnoDB

Comment: I followed all of steps, but It does not work yet. tomcat+spring+jsp forms

Comment: A note about Tomcat: as of Tomcat 8, the default `URIEncoding` on a `<Connector>` is now `UTF-8`, unless you are using strict spec-compliance (in which case it defaults to `ISO-8859` but can still be overridden).

Comment: What about InternetExplorer version <= 11, it isn't encode *ж* to %D0%A4 in URL: site.org?id=ж.
And Tomcat will throw the exception: 
"Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986".
What do we need in this case?

Answer (score 14):

I think you summed it up quite well in your own answer.

In the process of UTF-8-ing(?) from end to end you might also want to make sure java itself is using UTF-8. Use -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 as parameter to the JVM (can be configured in catalina.bat).

Comment: This helped me, I did everything mentioned but JVM encoding was windows-1250 as soon as I changed to UTF-8 it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Where do you add that in the Catalina.bat file, please?

Answer (score 12):

To add to [kosoant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138950/545127), if you are using Spring, rather than writing your own Servlet filter, you can use the class `org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter` they provide, configuring it like the following in your web.xml:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
       <param-value>FALSE</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: This filter must be the first filter in web.xml

Answer (score 2):

I want also to add from [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqI18nProjectEncoding) this part solved my utf problem:

```
runtime.encoding=<encoding>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for Greek Encoding in MySql tables when we want to access them using Java:

Use the following connection setup in your JBoss connection pool (mysql-ds.xml)

```
<connection-url>jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.123:3308/mydatabase</connection-url>
<driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
<user-name>nts</user-name>
<password>xaxaxa!</password>
<connection-property name="useUnicode">true</connection-property>
<connection-property name="characterEncoding">greek</connection-property>
```

If you don't want to put this in a JNDI connection pool, you can configure it as a JDBC-url like the next line illustrates:

```
jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.123:3308/mydatabase?characterEncoding=greek
```

For me and Nick, so we never forget it and waste time anymore.....

Comment: I would still prefer UTF-8 above Greek (and convert your current Greek data to UTF-8) so that your application is ready for world domination.

Answer (score 1):

Nice detailed answer. just wanted to add one more thing which will definitely help others to see the UTF-8 encoding on URLs in action .

Follow the steps below to enable UTF-8 encoding on URLs in firefox.

1. type "about:config" in the address bar.
2. Use the filter input type to search for "network.standard-url.encode-query-utf8" property.
3. the above property will be false by default, turn that to TRUE.
4. restart the browser.

UTF-8 encoding on URLs works by default in IE6/7/8 and chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Previous responses didn't work with my problem. It was only in production, with tomcat and apache mod_proxy_ajp. Post body lost non ascii chars by ?
The problem finally was with JVM defaultCharset (US-ASCII in a default instalation: Charset dfset = Charset.defaultCharset();)
so, the solution was run tomcat server with a modifier to run the JVM with UTF-8 as default charset:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

(add this line to catalina.sh and service tomcat restart)

Maybe you must also change linux system variable (edit ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile for permanent change, see https://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment)

> export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
>   export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>
> export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I'm with a similar problem, but, in filenames of a file I'm compressing with apache commons.
So, i resolved it with this command:

```
convmv --notest -f cp1252 -t utf8 * -r
```

it works very well for me. Hope it help anyone ;)

Answer (score 0):

For my case of displaying Unicode character from message bundles, I don't need to apply "JSP page encoding" section to display Unicode on my jsp page. All I need is "CharsetFilter" section.

Answer (score 0):

One other point that hasn't been mentioned relates to Java Servlets working with Ajax. I have situations where a web page is picking up utf-8 text from the user sending this to a JavaScript file which includes it in a URI sent to the Servlet. The Servlet queries a database, captures the result and returns it as XML to the JavaScript file which formats it and inserts the formatted response into the original web page.

In one web app I was following an early Ajax book's instructions for wrapping up the JavaScript in constructing the URI. The example in the book used the escape() method, which I discovered (the hard way) is wrong. For utf-8 you must use encodeURIComponent().

Few people seem to roll their own Ajax these days, but I thought I might as well add this.

Answer (score 0):

About `CharsetFilter` mentioned in @kosoant answer ....

There is a build in `Filter` in tomcat `web.xml` (located at `conf/web.xml`). The filter is named `setCharacterEncodingFilter` and is commented by default. You can uncomment this ( Please remember to uncomment its `filter-mapping` too )

Also there is no need to set `jsp-config` in your `web.xml` (I have test it for Tomcat 7+ )

Answer (score 0):

Some time you can solve problem through MySQL Administrator wizard. In

> Startup variables > Advanced >

and set   Def. char Set:utf8

Maybe this config need restart MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue on Spring MVC 5 + Tomcat 9 + JSP.
After the long research, came to an elegant solution (**no** need **filters** and **no** need **changes** in the Tomcat **server.xml** (starting from 8.0.0-RC3 version))

1. In the WebMvcConfigurer implementation set default encoding for messageSource (for reading data from messages source files in the UTF-8 encoding.

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvc
   @ComponentScan("{package.with.components}")
   public class WebApplicationContextConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

       @Bean
       public MessageSource messageSource() {
           final ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

           messageSource.setBasenames("messages");
           messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

           return messageSource;
       }

       /* other beans and methods */

   }
   ```
2. In the DispatcherServletInitializer implementation @Override the onStartup method and set request and resource character encoding in it.

   ```
   public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

       @Override
       public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

           // https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding
           servletContext.setRequestCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
           servletContext.setResponseCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

           super.onStartup(servletContext);
       }

       /* servlet mappings, root and web application configs, other methods */

   }
   ```
3. Save all message source and view files in UTF-8 encoding.
4. Add <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %> **or** <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %> in each *.jsp file **or** add jsp-config descriptor to web.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
       <display-name>AppName</display-name>

       <jsp-config>
           <jsp-property-group>
               <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
               <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
           </jsp-property-group>
       </jsp-config>
   </web-app>
   ```

Answer (score -1):

In case you have specified in connection pool (mysql-ds.xml), in your Java code you can open the connection as follows:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.12:3308/mydb?characterEncoding=greek",
    "Myuser", "mypass");
```