# Java convert Windows-1252 to UTF-8, some letters are wrong

Tags: java, utf-8, windows-1252

I receive data from a external Microsoft SQL 2008 database (I make queries with MyBatis). The data is encoded as "Windows-1252".

I have tried to re-encode to UTF-8:

```
String textoFormado = ...value from MyBatis... ; 
String s = new String(textoFormado.getBytes("Windows-1252"), "UTF-8");
```

Almost the whole string is correctly decoded, but some letters with accents  are not.

For example:

1. I received this: `Ã�vila`
2. The code above makes: `�?vila`
3. I expected: `Ávila`

Comment: Break your line into two statements, so you can get a look at the intermediate string.  That will help you see what the source of the problem might be.

Comment: Thank. But I tried String s = new String(mistring.getBytes("Windows-1252")); but the result is the same.

Comment: Your variable _textoFormado_ is already a string that you simply can use in your program. Why are thinking you must encode and decode it again?

Comment: Because this String have the text "Ã�vila" (it is recived from database from MyBatis) and I need "Ávila".

Comment: How are you retrieving the String from MyBatis? That is where you need to deal with a charset conversion from Windows-1252 to UTF-16 (Java's native String encoding). Even if you have to use `getBytes()`, you should be specifying `Windows-1252` instead of `UTF-8` in the `String` constructor since you are not dealing with UTF-8 bytes at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it thanks to all.

I have the next **project structure**:

- MyBatisQueries: I have a query with a "select" which gives me the String
- Pojo to save the String (which gave me the String with conversion problems)
- The class which uses the query and the Pojo object with data (that showed me bad decoded)

**at first I had**  (MyBatis and Spring inject dependencies and params):

```
public class Pojo {
    private String params;
    public void setParams(String params) {
        try {
            this.params = params;
        }
    }

}
```

**The solution:**

```
public class Pojo {
    private String params;
    public void setParams(byte[] params) {
        try {
            this.params = new String(params, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            this.params = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

Obviously, `textoFormado` is a variable of type `String`. This means that the bytes were already decoded. Java then internally uses a 16-bit Unicode representation. What you did, is to encode your string with Windows-1252 followed by reading the resulting bytes with an UTF-8 encoding. That does not work.

What you need is the correct encoding when reading the bytes:

```
byte[] sourceBytes = getRawBytes();
String data = new String(sourceBytes , "Windows-1252");
```

For using this string inside your program, you do not need to do anything. Simply use it. If - however - you want to write the data back to a file for example, you need to encode again:

```
byte[] destinationBytes = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
// write bytes to destination file here
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, it have sense and it give me some ideas.  But I use MyBatis for to launch queries to the database, this return me text in type String. I tried the next code for return back, but dont coded correctly:
byte[] textBytes = textoFormado.getBytes("UTF-8");
String value = new String(textBytes , "Windows-1252");

Comment: Use `textoFormado.getBytes("Windows-1252")` instead.  Forget about UTF-8, it does not apply in this situation, and you are not using it correctly anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Why not tackling the issue at a lower level: reading the String in proper encoding from your database.

Most JDBC *connection-string* or URIs support the property *characterEncoding*.

So in you Microsoft SQL Server case you could have for example `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:52865;databaseName=myDb?characterEncoding=utf8`.

Then each String column should be read in the specified encoding without the need to (re-)convert it manually to it.

See also:

- [JDBC character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040597/jdbc-character-encoding)
- [Problems reading/writing UTF-8 data in MySQL from Java using JDBC connector 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730359/problems-reading-writing-utf-8-data-in-mysql-from-java-using-jdbc-connector-5-1)