# MySQL database not saving non-latin characters in VARCHAR field correctly

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, character-encoding, collation

I am making an application where I fetch tweets and store them in a database for future editing and what I found is that my local database (run with XAMPP) stores non-latin characters as question marks.

For example:

**This is the tweeter status I see in the debugger of my IDE (NetBeans):**

[image: 1]

**This is the status in tweeter:**

[image: 2]

**This is the status in my database:**

[image: 3]

My source code is saved as UTF-8, `fullText` and `editedText` fields are both `varchar(255) utf8_general_mysql500_ci` and the Server Collation is `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Thanks, looks like I had to set the char encoding in the driver as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730359/problems-reading-writing-utf-8-data-in-mysql-from-java-using-jdbc-connector-5-1

Answer (score 0):

SqlServer **`varchar`** only supports single-byte-character-sets such as Latin-1.

If you have control of the database, try using **`nvarchar`** which supports double-byte character-sets.

varchar overview: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html

Latin-1 Supported characters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1