# UTF-8 character not supporting

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8

I am trying to add row in database as follows:

```
String query = "update Mutable e set e.Name = "Благодаря";
Statement s;
s.execute(query);
```

But it updates as ?????? in database. I am setting this name to a Russian string.
But if i run same query in MySQL query browser then it updates the name correctly.
I am not able to find the reason.

Comment: You have mismatched double-quotes in your code example. This isn't the cause of your problem, but tidying that up might make your example easier to read.

Comment: Single quote around blagodarja I assume.

Comment: You say it updates as "??????". How are you retrieving and displaying this value?

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730359/problems-reading-writing-utf-8-data-in-mysql-from-java-using-jdbc-connector-5-1

Comment: What is the character set of your DB ?

Comment: Already asked: [java mysql utf8 problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275524/java-mysql-utf8-problem)

Comment: Sorry for some typing errors.

Comment: @JoopEggen .. i saw answers for those questions but that doesn't solved this issue.

Comment: @Duncan  I retrieved that value from Database.

Comment: @user2324131 Please explain how you did that.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved. The problem was in my.cnf file. 
in the my.cnf file the default character set was latin1. which i changed to UTF8 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try

   "update Mutable e set e.Name = '\u0411\u043b\u0430\u0433\u43e\u00434\u0430\u0440\u044f'";

   This u-escaping to ASCII removes one problem: that the encoding of the java source text must be the same as the encoding used by the javac compiler.
2. Then easily the results can be displayed false in a Windows or IDE console with a non-Cyrillic encoding. Check the results in the database, as you did.

   You can check the value indirect:

   ```
   System.out.println("Okay: " + !fieldValue.contains("?"));
   ```
3. Verify that the connection string is something like:

   ```
   "jdbc:mysql:///dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8"
   ```

   which ensures that the driver communication uses UTF-8.

Comment: I tried this. But when i type this line then the eclipse editor throws Error "Invalid Unicode".

Comment: @Pratik all unicode should be 4 digits, not 3 or 5. BTW once the code is compiled they shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: This issue is resolved. The problem was in my.cnf file. in the my.cnf file the default character set was latin1. which i changed to UTF8 and it worked.