# UTF-8 encoding and http parameters

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I am doing a simple ajax call with the YahooUI Javascript library as follows:

```
YAHOO.util.Connect.setForm('myform');
YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', url, ...);
```

Following are the settings in my app:
Tomcat version: 6.0.18

Tomcat server connector : URIEncoding="UTF-8"
webapp page :

Also stated in YahooUI connector library docs:

> setForm will encode each HTML form
>   field's name and value using
>   encodeURIComponent. This results in a
>   string of UTF-8 encoded, name-value
>   pairs. NOTE: Setting an HTTP header of
>   "Content-Type" with a different
>   charset value will not change the
>   encoding of the serialized data.encoding of the serialized data.

I can see that the french characters that are being sent as parameters are encoded (in ie7 using iehttpheader tool):

```
    name=%C3%88%C3%A0%C3%B4 
    testParam=%C3%B4%C3%B4
```

For the data :
name: Èàô
and testParam: ôô

But on the server side I am seeing values as following:
ÃƒÂˆÃƒÂ ÃƒÂ

Even if I am converting the string to bytes and then create new string with the charset defined as follows:
     String val = new String(oo.getBytes("UTF-8"));
I am not able to get the exact data as expected.

Note: I have referenced the question below, but was not able to resolve this issue: [How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps) Please guide.

**UPDATE:** 
Calling the decode UTF-8 function as given on W3.org site http://www.w3.org/International/O-URL-code.html is giving me the expected results. I expect Tomcat to be decoding this?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using a `POST` query, `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` is not applicable here. You need to set a filter to tell Tomcat that your request encoding is UTF-8. You may use, for example, a Spring's `CharacterEncodingFilter` ([usage](http://ibnaziz.wordpress.com/2008/06/10/spring-utf-8-conversion-using-characterencodingfilter/), [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html)). Other implementations of such filters can also be found.

Comment: Yes this worked - I had to ensure that the filter which I had applied(SetCharacterEncodingFilter - which is available in tomcat examples folder) had to be the first one which is invoked before my other filters and it worked!. Thanks :)

Comment: Here is another usage link since the one above seems broken: http://azizsaboor.wordpress.com/2008/06/10/spring-utf-8-conversion-using-characterencodingfilter/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here is one:

```
package com.lfantastico.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

public class EncodingFilter implements Filter {
    private String encoding = "UTF-8";

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        if (config.getInitParameter("encoding") != null) {
            encoding = config.getInitParameter("encoding");
        }
    }
}
```