# Why does POST not honor charset, but an AJAX request does? tomcat 6

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, servlets, character-encoding

I have a tomcat based application that needs to submit a form capable of handling utf-8 characters. When submitted via ajax, the data is returned correctly from getParameter() in utf-8. When submitting via form post, the data is returned from getParameter() in iso-8859-1.

I used fiddler, and have determined the *only* difference in the requests, is that **charset=utf-8** is appended to the end of the **Content-Type** header in the ajax call (as expected, since I send the content type explicitly).

ContentType from ajax:
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"

ContentType from form:
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

I have the following settings:

ajax post (outputs chars correctly):

```
$.ajax( {
  type : "POST",
  url : "blah",
  async : false,
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
  data  : data,
  success : function(data) { 
  }
 });
```

form post (outputs chars in iso)

```
 <form id="leadform" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="{//app/path}">
```

xml declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

jvm parameters:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

I have also tried using **request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");** but it seems as if tomcat simply ignores it. I am not using the RequestDumper valve.

From what I've read, POST data encoding is mostly dependent on the page encoding where the form is. As far as I can tell, my page is correctly encoded in utf-8.

The sample JSP from this page works correctly.  It simply uses **setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");** and echos the data you post.    http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

So to summarize, the post request does not send the charset as being utf-8, despite the page being in utf-8, the form parameters specifying utf-8, the xml declaration or anything else. I have spent the better part of three days on this and am running out of ideas.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: then it sounds like it's not a tomcat issue but a browser issue since it seems tomcat is able to correctly handle incoming UTF requests no? Fiddler is pre-tomcat. Have you tried this in different browsers?

Comment: tested in firefox 3.6.12/linux, firefox 3.6.3/winxp , chrome 7.0.517.44/linux, 8.0.552.215/winxp, safari 4.03 winxp. results are the same across the board.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> form post (outputs chars in iso)
>
> ```
> <form id="leadform" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="{//app/path}">
> ```

You don't need to specify the charset there. The browser will use the charset which is specified in HTTP 
response header.

Just

```
<form id="leadform" method="post" action="{//app/path}">
```

is enough.

---

> xml declaration:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> ```

Irrelevant. It's only relevant for XML parsers. Webbrowsers doesn't parse `text/html` as XML. This is only relevant for the server side (if you're using a XML based view technology like Facelets or JSPX, on plain JSP this is superfluous).

---

> Doctype:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
> ```

Irrelevant. It's only relevant for HTML parsers. Besides, it doesn't specify any charset. Instead, the one in the HTTP response header will be used. If you aren't using a XML based view technology like Facelets or JSPX, this can be as good `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

---

> meta tag:
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
> ```

Irrelevant. It's only relevant when the HTML page is been viewed from local disk or is to be parsed locally. Instead, the one in the HTTP response header will be used.

---

> jvm parameters:
>
> ```
> -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
> ```

Irrelevant. It's only relevant to Sun/Oracle(!) JVM to parse the source files.

---

> I have also tried using `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` but it seems as if tomcat simply ignores it. I am not using the RequestDumper valve.

This will only work when the request body is not been parsed yet (i.e. you haven't called `getParameter()` and so on beforehand). You need to call this as early as possible. A `Filter` is a perfect place for this. Otherwise it will be ignored.

---

> From what I've read, POST data encoding is mostly dependent on the page encoding where the form is. As far as I can tell, my page is correctly encoded in utf-8.

It's dependent on the HTTP response header.

All you need to do are the following three things:

1. Add the following to top of your JSP:

   ```
   <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
   ```

   This will set the response encoding to UTF-8 and set the response header to UTF-8.
2. Create a `Filter` which does the following in `doFilter()` method:

   ```
   if (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
       request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   }
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
   ```

   This will make that the POST request body will be processed as UTF-8.
3. Change the `<Connector>` entry in `Tomcat/conf/server.xml` as follows:

   ```
   <Connector (...) URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
   ```

   This will make that the GET query strings will be processed as UTF-8.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) - contains practical background information and detailed solutions for Java EE web developers.

Comment: best answer in all questions of this subject!

Comment: `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` as early as possible (in filter) helped me with form submitting encoding issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
How do I change how POST parameters are interpreted?
```

POST requests should specify the encoding of the parameters and values they send. Since many clients fail to set an explicit encoding, the default is used (ISO-8859-1). In many cases this is not the preferred interpretation so one can employ a javax.servlet.Filter to set request encodings. Writing such a filter is trivial. Furthermore Tomcat already comes with such an example filter.

Please take a look at:

```
5.x

webapps/servlets-examples/WEB-INF/classes/filters/SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java

webapps/jsp-examples/WEB-INF/classes/filters/SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java

6.x

webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/filters/SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java
```

For more info , refer to the below URL
http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

Comment: thats what i used as a reference, and have used to ultimately solve the problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `accept-charset="UTF-8"`? As you said, the data should be encoded according to the encoding of the page itself; it seems strange that tomcat is ignoring that. What browser are you trying this out on?

Comment: vivin, i have tried this in firefox 3.6.12/linux, firefox 3.6.3/winxp , chrome 7.0.517.44/linux, 8.0.552.215/winxp, safari 4.03/winxp.

i have indeed tried accept-charset="UTF-8" , it had no discernible effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify `useBodyEncodingForURL="true"` in your `conf/server.xml` for HTTP connector?

Comment: It's a POST body, and the body is being sent as ISO,so I didn't think encoding the url string itself the same as the body will help, but I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a filter based on the information in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps) and it is now working.  However, this still doesn't explain why even though the page was UTF-8, the charset used by tomcat to interpret it was ISO-9951-1.

Comment: What is ur browser ? It might depends on client software as well