# getting set of question marks (??????) as result while retrieving non english text stored in database using Hibernate - JavaEE

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, special-characters

I've been trying to build an application that stores text contents in any language into my database and retrieve the same. 
**I am using postgres as my database and Hibernate as db framework.**

The problem is that when i try to store a text into database using hibernate , it is getting printed in a different format in the javaEE server.

for eg: a text that i entered in the input box as  **" ജനുവരി "** in malayalam is getting printed as **" �?ന�?വരി "** in the javaEE server.

The same scenario , when i tried using normal **php** code and **php-postgres db connection** is working fine. I am able to store language eg. hindi, tamil, telugu,malayalam etc into database and can retrieve and show in the html page without any troubles or loss of content. In this case i am able to read the content even through the pg-admin (postgres workbench) console.

But this same content , when i tries to fetch using javaEE hibernate query, i am getting a result like **'?????????'** even though i am able to read the actual content through the workbench.

**I tried to set UTF8 encoding to my hibernate config file . but nothing seems to be working .** 
**any help on this will be greatly appreciated.**

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: I think you need to change your database Encoding to UTF-8 not hibernate.

Comment: Hi, my database is postgres and its db server encoding is "UTF8" by default.I tried by setting the database encoding as "utf8" inside my hibernate-config file. but even that didn't helps.

Comment: BalusC has marked this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108466/unicode-characters-in-servlet-application-are-shown-as-question-marks . but like the answer in that question, i am not using any jsp pages. I am using hibernate and java only in my server side and my client application is android.

Comment: Do you use java servlets to generate the html responses? Maybe the response encoding is wrong.