# Bad UTF-8 encoding when writing to database (reading is OK)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jpa, character-encoding

I have big problem in my web application using **JSF** and **EclipseLink JPA** to **MySQL** database.

When I read data from database JSF reads and writes my charachters in UTF-8 OK. but in database characters are bad.

f.e.: input characters: "żźćółzxcv", written in database: "?????zxcv".
But if I manually write data to database, for example: "żźćółzxcv", then reading in JSF is perfect.

I tried everything from here: [Unicode input retrieved via PrimeFaces input components become corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634230/typing-chinese-with-primefaces-peditor-component/9839362#9839362)

And I discovered that encoding in JSF is fine, but the problem is in java, becouse if I set manually

```
current.setUwagiZ("żźćóżźćłąśóżźćł TE");
getFacade().edit(current);
```

in database record is wrong: `???ó??????ó???? TE`

I have set characterEncoding and useUnicode in JDBC Resource. Also when execute commands by some tools in NetBeans encoding is OK and data in MySQL are in UTF-8, so connections seems fine.

So the problem is java, but I completely don't know how to solve this :(

Comment: Are you sure the client you are using to browse the database can handle UTF-8?

Comment: I think so, because problem is only when I want to insert or edit data

Comment: Try it also with a hardcoded insert of "ĉ\u0109" which should give twice a c-circumflex. And check the table and field definition in the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Question marks can occur when the messenger itself is aware about the character encoding used in the both sides of the transport. That's the difference with [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) whereby it's not the messenger's fault, but the producer's and/or consumer's fault.

In an average web application with a database backend, there are only 2 places where this can happen: communication with the DB and communication with the HTTP client. You've already excluded the HTTP part, so left behind the DB part.

The messenger in the DB part is the JDBC driver. You need to tell the JDBC driver to use UTF-8. MySQL JDBC driver is known to use by default the client platform default encoding, which is in your particular case apparently not UTF-8.

Add the following 2 properties to the JDBC connection:

- `useUnicode=true`
- `characterEncoding=UTF-8`

It's unclear how you've configured the JDBC connection, but if it's "plain vanilla" JDBC, then specify them as query string in JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Or if it's a container-specific datasource config, then specify them as separate connection properties, exactly the same way as you specify the username and password.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: I have: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/b2b?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8 but it doesn't work

Comment: Where exactly is this been set? In e.g. a datasource in server configuration those properties can't go in URL, they needs to be definied as separate properties (exactly like username and password). You didn't give much detail about that part, but your term "JDBC Resource" sounds much like the one in Glassfish admin console.

Comment: I tried both: in gassfish I added this 2 properties and also in persistence.xml I added to Data Source this jdbc

Comment: AAAAAAA! I noticed that it still marked the old JDBC without setting this 2 properties in persistence.xml! Now everything works! Thanks a lot!