# Java UTF-8 encoding issue - getting garbled values like Ã as Ã<9c> and Ü as Ã� in tomcat logs

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, httprequest

I was getting unicode issue while encoding special characters.
In my html, I am passing Special characters like 'Ã' , 'Ü' to post method to call java action class.
Now, in tomcat logs I am getting garbled values like 'Ã<9c>' , Ã�

Thanks to @BalusC your post - [How to pass Unicode characters as JSP/Servlet request.getParameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517268/why-do-unicode-characters-get-broken-in-a-jsp-servlet-request-getparameter) solved my problem. Now, I am able to get correct values.

Solution - Depending upon the request type, UTF-8 encoding can be configured as following :

•   For Get requests, we need to  configure at the servlet container level by adding ‘URIEncoding’ attribute in  element in tomcat/conf/server.xml

•   For POST requests, create a filter which is mapped on the desired URL pattern for POST requests & set Character encoding as ‘UTF-8‘.

Thanks

Comment: What Java code generate that?

Comment: Java code converted 'Ã' as 'Ã9c' and 'Ü' as 'Ã�'

Comment: Is that a JSP file ?

Comment: it is not my question, how did you generate this html file ?

Comment: created html file using java variables and used request.getParameter()

Comment: @JatinGupta Please update your question with additional information such as this.  You can click the `edit` link below the question (directly above these comments) to revise the question.  This type of information is not suitable for a comment, as it's exceptionally difficult to read.  Your question should be self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Your charset is set to 8859-1 (`charset=ISO-8859-1`) and you use UTF-8 charactes, so I assume you have wrongly configured locale on the server or in the application.

Without seeing the code it is hard to guess, but I would check the output of `locale` command.

Comment: the characters are already incorrect in the generated file, what we have in meta is indeed incorrect but is not the root cause here

Comment: Thanks @BalusC Your post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517268/why-do-unicode-characters-get-broken-in-a-jsp-servlet-request-getparameter solved my problem. 
Depending upon the request type, UTF-8 encoding can be configured as following :

• For Get requests, we need to  configure at the servlet container level by adding ‘URIEncoding’ attribute in <Connector> element in tomcat/conf/server.xml
• For POST requests, create a filter which is mapped on the desired URL pattern for POST requests & set Character encoding as ‘UTF-8‘.

Thanks