# Accented characters in Java source file are not displayed correctly in a JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, character-encoding, bean-validation

I have a *CDI* bean in a *JSF* application with this property:

```
@NotNull(message = "Senha não informada.")
public String getSenha()
{
    return _senha;
}
```

The problem is that when validation fails the message displayed on the page is this:

*Senha nÃ£o informada.*

The problem is not with *JSF*, but with *Bean Validation*, because if I place the message in a standard *JSF* validator and use it instead of the bean validation annotation, the message is displayed correctly with the right accented characters.

I tried changing the request and response encoding to *UTF-8* in a filter to see if the problem was fixed, but the problem remains.

Of course, if I change the annotation message to this *Senha n\u00e3o informada.* I get the right message on the page, but I don't want this. I want a way to instruct the bean validation API (or another thing) to use the accented characters in my own language.

I'm using *Wildfly 10* with all default libraries.

*P.S.*: I don't want to use a message bundle for my messages.

Comment: This can happen if the Java source file itself is not saved using UTF-8 by the editor and/or not being read using UTF-8 by the compiler. Answer depends on tooling used. Javac CLI? Eclipse? Maven? Etc.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and the _Text file encoding_ of the Workspace is configured to use _UTF-8_. I'm also using the Gradle plugin Buildship in Eclipse with this project.

Comment: And what's the build tool? Eclipse itself or Maven (via e.g. m2e)?

Comment: The build tool is Gradle (with Buildship plugin)

Comment: Ah okay, sorry I don't do Gradle, but in Maven you'd need to set `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>` property in `pom.xml`. Perhaps Gradle has something similar.

Comment: I will check this and report my findings later.

Comment: Nice catch, @BalusC. The configuration in Gradle is `tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {options.encoding = 'UTF-8'}` and it solved the problem. Maybe you would like to give it as an answer so I can mark it as answered. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if the Java source file itself is not saved using UTF-8 by the editor and/or not being read using UTF-8 by the compiler. Answer depends on the tooling used. It boils down to reconfiguring the tooling to use UTF-8.

In case of Eclipse, you need to make sure that workspace text file encoding is set to UTF-8 as shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukrYs.png) ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10517268)). This will make Eclipse to save Java source files using UTF-8, build the project using UTF-8 and also to use UTF-8 in output console.

In case you're using Maven to build the project, then you need to add the below entries to `pom.xml`. The reporting output encoding isn't required to solve your specific problem, but it's handy.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

In case you're using Gradle to build the project, it can be solved with below configuration, as confirmed in your comment on the question.

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {options.encoding = 'UTF-8'}
```

Comment: Thank you again for the answer.

Comment: I was thinking about this to, but due to this remark by the OP: _"The problem is not with JSF, but with Bean Validation, because if I place the message in a standard JSF validator and use it instead of the bean validation annotation, the message is displayed correctly with the right accented characters."_ I thought it might be something else.

Comment: @Kukeltje and this is true indeed.

Comment: @Marcos? So was the above thing the answer or not? Now you got me confused even more...

Comment: @Kukeltje sorry for this. In my last comment I meant that what I said was really true, as cited by you. When I use standard _JSF_ validators the message is displayed correctly. But _Bean Validation_ is really taking a different approach than _JSF_ to encode the validation messages, that's why they are not displayed with the correct accents.

Comment: So you meant a jsf validator in xhtml, not a 'custom' jsf validator in java? The latter is what I was assuming... Hence I thought that it could not be dependent on the java tooling saving it in a wrong way.

Comment: If, for example, I use this in a _JSF_ _xhtml_ page `<h:inputSecret value="#{bean.senha}" required="true" requiredMessage="Senha não informada." />` the message is displayed correctly. If I use a _JSF_ validator on the xhtml page too. But this is not the case with the _Bean Validation_ annotation. I didn't test with a custom _JSF_ validator, but I suppose that the message would be displayed correctly with it too, as it comes from _JSF_.

Comment: No it would have been wrong to since it would have been in java and fail the same as the bean-validator. So the problem was not that JSF was working and bean-validation was not, the problem was that your java code was not UTF-8

Comment: @Kukeltje Makes sense.