# Get unicode string in java servlet submitted from HTML form?

Tags: java, servlets, unicode, utf-8, servlet-3.1

I stuck up while working with Unicode(Nepali) in Servlet. Well I submit  (POST Method)  HTML form and wanted to store in database. But could not get exact unicode.

I tried following things -

1. `new String(request.getParameter("nameNep").getBytes("iso-8859-1"),"utf-8")`

Result of above code is `?????? ????` like string

2. `byte[] utf8Bytes = request.getParameter("nameNep").("UTF8");
   String text = new String(utf8Bytes,"UTF8");`

this code generate text like `à¤®à¤?à¤¦à¥?à¤° à¤?à¤¨`, and is actually same result as `request.getParameter("nameNep")`

3. `URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("nameNep"), "UTF-8");`

same result as 2

4. `request.setCharacterSet("UTF-8");`
   setting this up before any action on request, got same result as 2 & 3

What i am doing mistake here , the form field nameNep contains nepali Unicode characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass Unicode characters as JSP/Servlet request.getParameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517268/how-to-pass-unicode-characters-as-jsp-servlet-request-getparameter)