# Replace is not replacing double quotes in java

Tags: java, replace

I have a below string which is coming from the application:

```
Hotel “Lowest Rate Guaranteed” Terms and Conditions
```

I am trying to replace double quotes in the above statement using following line:

```
Tempdata = Tempdata.replace("\"", "");
System.out.println(Tempdata);
```

It's not working and always returning the same value but if I manually remove the above double quote and enter the double quote manually and try the same command, it works fine.

After replacing the double quote manually, the string looks like

```
Hotel "Lowest Rate Guaranteed" Terms and Conditions
```

We can see there is minor difference in the double quote. Look like the double quote which is coming from application is utf-8.

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Why not replace all types of double quotes? `Tempdata.replace("\"", "").replace("“","")..replace("”","");`

Comment: Why? Why not preserve the data as it is?

Comment: Thanks TT. Your solution is working :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just copy the double quotes into the replace, the respective codes are `\u201c` and `\u201d`.

Alternatively you could use a regular expression such as `[\"'\u2018\u2019\u201c\u201d]` to match all quotes. (Not however those characters often misused as quotation marks. I'm looking at you, `grave and acute´)

Where

- `"` matches `"`
- `'` matches `'`
- `\u2018` matches `‘` (left single quotation mark)
- `\u2019` matches `’` (right single quotation mark)
- `\u201c` matches `“` (left double quotation mark)
- `\u201d` matches `”` (right double quotation mark)

An example of this could be just using `String.replaceAll()`:

```
tempdata = tempdata.replaceAll("[\"'\u2018\u2019\u201c\u201d]", "")
```

Or, if you need to do this often, compiling the pattern and saving is more efficient:

Somewhere in your class:

```
private final Pattern quotation = Pattern.compile("[\"'\u2018\u2019\u201c\u201d]")
```

And then further down:

```
quotation.matcher(tempdata).replaceAll("")
```

On an unrelated note, don't give variables capital names in Java, it burns my eyes and is against all common convention. Giving them the same name as a class is extra evil.

Comment: I thought this was surely the answer to my problem but it is not working. 


I am processing a form field in a jsp template. 

The input sometimes has " " " but it can also have the stupidity of " “ "   which you can't tell here is the "curly" double quotes ( \201c  and \u201d ). (bloody windows). 

After the form is submitted, the field data is turned to a string in the parameter handler it shows up as  "?" , how do I escape any occurrences of those curly double quotes???

using:

formfieldstring.replace('\u201c',"\"")

:is not working at all.

Comment: Obvious aside, replace takes two chars. Otherwise, your problem sounds like an encoding issue. Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002827/passing-request-parameters-as-utf-8-encoded-strings

Comment: May I suggest to add \u201e left lower double quotation mark