# Strings with high Unicode characters become corrupted when passing from Javascript to Java

Tags: javascript, java, react-native, unicode

I am passing a string from Javascript to a React Native native Java module and then back to Javascript. However, any high Unicode characters such as emojis become corrupted after passing it to Java and turn into a pair of question marks.

For example, the string `"testing123"` becomes `"testing123??"`

How can I fix this so that the characters retain their values?

**EDIT:** The string is being processed by a React Native background upload library. Here is an excerpt of the code from that library that passes the text (which is in the `parameters` field) to the Java module:

```
import { NativeModules, DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native'
export type StartUploadArgs = {
  url: string,
  path: string,
  method?: 'PUT' | 'POST',
  // Optional, because raw is default
  type?: 'raw' | 'multipart',
  // This option is needed for multipart type
  field?: string,
  customUploadId?: string,
  // parameters are supported only in multipart type
  parameters?: { [string]: string },
  headers?: Object,
  notification?: NotificationArgs
}
const NativeModule = NativeModules.VydiaRNFileUploader || NativeModules.RNFileUploader // iOS is VydiaRNFileUploader and Android is NativeModules
//...
export const startUpload = (options: StartUploadArgs): Promise<string> => NativeModule.startUpload(options)
```

And here is an excerpt of the Java code that handles the string:

```
  @ReactMethod
  public void startUpload(ReadableMap options, final Promise promise) {
//...
      HttpUploadRequest<?> request;

      if (requestType.equals("raw")) {
        request = new BinaryUploadRequest(this.getReactApplicationContext(), customUploadId, url)
                .setFileToUpload(filePath);
      } else {
        if (!options.hasKey("field")) {
          promise.reject(new IllegalArgumentException("field is required field for multipart type."));
          return;
        }

        if (options.getType("field") != ReadableType.String) {
          promise.reject(new IllegalArgumentException("field must be string."));
          return;
        }

        request = new MultipartUploadRequest(this.getReactApplicationContext(), customUploadId, url)
                .addFileToUpload(filePath, options.getString("field"));
      }


      request.setMethod(method)
        .setMaxRetries(2)
        .setDelegate(statusDelegate);
//...
      if (options.hasKey("parameters")) {
        if (requestType.equals("raw")) {
          promise.reject(new IllegalArgumentException("Parameters supported only in multipart type"));
          return;
        }

        ReadableMap parameters = options.getMap("parameters");
        ReadableMapKeySetIterator keys = parameters.keySetIterator();

        while (keys.hasNextKey()) {
          String key = keys.nextKey();

          if (parameters.getType(key) != ReadableType.String) {
            promise.reject(new IllegalArgumentException("Parameters must be string key/values. Value was invalid for '" + key + "'"));
            return;
          }
          request.addParameter(key, parameters.getString(key));
        }
      }
//...
      String uploadId = request.startUpload();
      promise.resolve(uploadId);
  }
```

Comment: Please share your Java code that is ingesting this string. It's like an encoding issue there.

Comment: You need to escape unicode character before passing to Java or any other platform for that matter. Refer to [this](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/1243213) method.

Comment: Start by showing the code that sends the string from JavaScript to java - you're probably doing something wrong with encoding there. Alternatively but less likely, you're doing something wrong in the receiving side.

Comment: I've updated the question with the JS and Java code that handles the string.

Answer (score 1):

The java servlet specification assumes form params are ISO-8859-1 by default.  Assuming you are using tomcat see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Character+Encoding for info on how to resolve this issue

Relevant quote from the page

> POST requests should specify the encoding of the parameters and values
>   they send. Since many clients fail to set an explicit encoding, the
>   default used is US-ASCII for application/x-www-form-urlencoded and
>   ISO-8859-1 for all other content types.

Related SO post https://stackoverflow.com/a/19409520/1967484

Keep in mind its also possible for your console and your database to also not support high unicode characters.

Comment: I am not using a Java servlet in my application. The Java side sends the string to a Node server, but it seems like the text gets corrupted before being sent.

Comment: Your ?? problem is clear sign of a encoding issue. Making sure you set the charset on every http request made in the process and it will probably fix your problem

Comment: This was the issue. The background upload library I'm using wasn't exposing a method to set the charset to UTF-8, but once I set it manually it worked properly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the background upload library's code like this fixed the issue:

```
request = new MultipartUploadRequest(this.getReactApplicationContext(), customUploadId, url)
        .addFileToUpload(filePath, options.getString("field"))
        .setUtf8Charset(); // add this line
```