# CharacterEncodingFilter not translating unicode text in Spring MVC 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, utf-8, character-encoding

I set `CharacterEncodingFilter` as the first filter in my web.xml:

```
<filter>  
 <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
 <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
 <init-param>  
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
 </init-param>  
 <init-param>  
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
    <param-value>true</param-value>  
 </init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
 <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

and in my JSPs this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8" isELIgnored="false" %>
```

and this:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

But, for example, `Tá` passed from a JSP form back to a controller and then back out to a JSP again becomes: `T%E`

I'm done hours of Google searches but can't find the answer to this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your controller do anything with the form data such as store it in a database, or does it simply put it back into the JSP? In other words, could this be a problem with the encoding on your database connection?

Comment: Are you using ajax to send the form and receive the data?

Comment: Are you sure your browser sends the correct headers (you can use Firebug)? Is the method of your form GET or POST?

Comment: all three very good questions :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Tomcat you might not have set the `URIEncoding` in your `server.xml`. If you don't set it to UTF-8 it won't work. Definitely keep the `CharacterEncodingFilter`. Nevertheless, here's a concise [checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps) to follow. It will definitely guide you to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

If `CharacterEncodingFilter` or the filter you implement is at the top of `web.xml`, be sure to also have the `<filter-mapping>` elements for the `CharacterEncodingFilter` in the xml appear before other `<filter-mapping>` elements for other filters.

Took me a long time to figure that out. Could be useful for someone.