# URL decoding Japanese characters etc. in Java

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding, url-encoding

I have a servlet that receives some POST data. Because this data is x-www-form-urlencoded, a string such as サボテン would be encoded to &#12469;&#12508;&#12486;&#12531;.

How would I unencode this string back to the correct characters? I have tried using `URLDecoder.decode("encoded string", "UTF-8");` but it doesn't make a difference.

The reason I would like to unencode them, is because, before I display this data on a webpage, I escape & to &amp; and at the moment, it is escaping the &s in the encoded string so the characters are not showing up properly.

Comment: Answer by BalusC is correct wrt this using XML entity encoding, not URL encoding; but is the response actually XML? If it was, should just use XML parser -- and if not, service seems broken as one should return XML as XML, not just text fragments from within a doc.

Comment: There's isn't any XML is there? The characters are received as HTML entities and sent back as HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are **not** [URL encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). It would have looked like `%E3%82%B5%E3%83%9C%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3`. Those are [decimal HTML/XML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference). To unescape HTML/XML entities, use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html).

---

**Update** as per the comments: you will get question marks when the response encoding is not UTF-8. If you're using JSP, just add the following line to top of the page:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

See for more detail the solutions about halfway [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html). I would prefer using-UTF8-all-the-way above fiddling with regexps since regexps doesn't prepare you for world domination.

Comment: Right, I tried StringEscapeUtils and it turns Japanese characters into ?s. So I think I will just not unencode and encode them again, rather I will use a regular expression to ignore the leading & when replacing & with &amp;

Comment: Ok, I'm using servlets, not JSP, but I will have a look at the article. Good encoding is definitely preferable to being unequipped for when the machines take over.

Comment: @DanieL - It isn't StringEscapeUtils that is turning the kana into `'?'`. That happens when the kana (text stored in Java's 16-bit `char` type) is "encoded" into a stream of bytes. If the character encoding in use (defaults to ISO-8859-1, which is designed for western European languages) doesn't recognize a character, it will substitute a `'?'`. You need to use a more internationalization-friendly encoding like UTF-8. If this app caters to Japanese, you can use something like Shift-JIS, which is more space efficient (but can't handle other characters like Cyrillic or Thai).

Comment: @DanieL: in a servlet, do `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` and accordingly `response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");`. Note that printing HTML in a servlet instead of delegating the job to the JSP is not the best practice...

Comment: I think I may have broken things a bit more, but you're saying I should receive the String with the entities etc. unescape it into a UTF-8 String and use that for all future purposes (output, database etc.)?

Comment: Since I have changed the encoding of the page to UTF-8, I have received the string as ãµããã³. Would I be correct in saying that this is because Tomcat os not handling the string properly?

Comment: This can happen when you encode the string as bytes using the incorrect encoding because you're "forced" to write them as bytes like `response.getOutputStream().write(string.getBytes())`. This will use the platform default encoding to convert chars to bytes which is not UTF-8 per se. You shouldn't be using outputstream to write character data, but a writer: `response.getWriter().write(string)`. Or, even better, use JSP as presentation. Note that I assume that you *did* set the response encoding as suggested in the answer and comment. Tomcat has nothing to do with this all.

Comment: Yes, I set the page encoding. But now when I print out the raw string received from the POST it displays as ãµããã³.

Comment: Turns out I needed to do **request**.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"). Hopefully I can get it all working from here. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Yes, when the page itself is instructed to use UTF-8, then the browser will just send the form data unescaped back as UTF-8, which you have to process as UTF-8 then (see also the linked article). After all you don't need the `StringEscapeUtils` then.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature/bug of browsers. If a web page is in a limited charset, say ASCII, and users type in some chars outside the charset in a form field, browsers will send these chars in the form of `$#xxxx;`

It can be a problem because if users actually type `$#xxxx;` they'll be sent as is. So the server has no way to distinguish the two cases.

The best way is to use a charset that covers all characters, like UTF-8, so browsers won't do this trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but are you using Tomcat?

If so, make sure you have set up the Connector in Tomcat with a URIEncoding of UTF-8. Google that on the web and you will find a ton of hits such as

[How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps)

Comment: Yes I am, I've set the URIEncoding to UTF-8, but it hasn't made a difference, most likely because, as @BalusC pointed out, I am talking about HTML entities, not URL encoding.

Comment: Tomcat's URIEncoding applies to the URI in the first line of the HTTP request, *not* to the body of a POST request.

Comment: Exactly. It applies on GET only, not on POST.

Answer (score 0):

How about a regular expression?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("&([^a][^m][^p][^;])?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
String output = matcher.replaceAll("&amp;$1");
```

Comment: I think I will have to use a regular expression to replace & with &amp; and ignore the HTML entities, but your one turns &#12469;&#12508;&#12486;&#12531; into &amp;69;&amp;08;&amp;86;&amp;31;

Comment: Alright, I've got "&(?!#\\d+;)" working. Is there any modifications that I should do to it?

Comment: I've just modified my example to replace the matched expression. It should work now.

Comment: It works, but it appears to do the same thing as replaceAll("&", "&amp;"). What I am trying to do is replace all the & with &amp; except for html entities like &#12469;