# How to correctly write UTF-8 strings into MySQL through JDBC interface

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, utf-8

Connect to db:

```
public DBSource(ConnectionInfo ci) throws
        ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException, SQLException
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    String dbPath = String.format(
        "jdbc:mysql://%s:%d/%s?user=%s&password=%s&characterEncoding=utf-8&" + 
        "useUnicode=true", ci.host, ci.port, ci.dbName, ci.user, ci.password);
    conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(dbPath);
    prepareTables();
}
```

Table creation code:

```
private void prepareTables() throws SQLException
{
    java.sql.Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

    String query = "set names utf8";
    stat.execute(query);

    query = "set character set utf8";
    stat.execute(query);

    query = "show variables like '%char%'";
    stat.execute(query);
    java.sql.ResultSet rs = stat.getResultSet();
    while (rs.next())
    {
        String k = rs.getString(1);
        String v = rs.getString(2);
        System.out.println(k + " - " + v);
    }
    
    query = "drop table if exists clt";
    stat.execute(query);
    query = "create table clt"
            + "("
            + "  id bigint not null"
            + ", text varchar(50) not null"
            + ") default character set utf8";
    stat.execute(query);
}
```

rows insertion:

```
public void visit(Insert i) throws SQLException
{
    String query = "insert into clt"
            + " (id, text) values (?, ?)";
    java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    if (i.rowData.id == 12656697)
    {
        String toOut = "<<< " + Long.toString(i.rowData.id) + " - " + i.rowData.text;
        System.out.println(toOut);
    }
    int it = 0;
    stmt.setLong(++it, i.rowData.id);
    stmt.setString(++it, i.rowData.text);
    stmt.execute();
    stmt.close();
}
```

check data:

```
 public void checkText() throws SQLException
{
    java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String query = "select id, text from clt where id = '12656697'";
    stmt.execute(query);
    java.sql.ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    while (rs.next())
    {
        String k = rs.getString(1);
        String v = rs.getString(2);
        String toOut = ">>> " + k + " - " + v;
        System.out.println(toOut);
    }
}
```

output:

```
character_set_client - utf8
character_set_connection - latin1
character_set_database - latin1
character_set_filesystem - binary
character_set_results - utf8
character_set_server - utf8
character_set_system - utf8
character_sets_dir - /usr/share/mysql/charsets/

<<< 12656697 - Апарати
>>> 12656697 - ???????
```

**Problem**: In table I have "*???????????*" symbols at the text field.

**expected string is**: *Апарати*
**result**: *???????*

It is some kind of **magic**?

I resolved an issue... But still will appreciate if somebody can explain it to me.

So.

1. I added to my /etc/mysql/my.cnf lines suggested by Costis Aivalis
   result the same
2. I removed lines from my code:
   query = "set character set utf8";
   stat.execute(query);

**it is working!!! :)**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456313/cant-insert-chinese-character-into-mysql/43389703#43389703

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ensure that your MySQL configuration encoding is defined correctly. Check your settings and the correctness of the modifications with these commands:

```
show variables like 'character%';
```

and `show variables like 'collation%';`

Add these lines to either **my.cnf** or **my.ini**:

For MySQL 5.1.nn, and later versions 5.5.29  you just need these two lines:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
character-set-filesystem = utf8
```

For MySQL 5.0.nn and older use these settings:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
```

```
[mysqld]
default-character-set=utf8
character-set-server=utf8
```

It is probably more convenient to use [MySQL-Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) for your settings. Versions 5+ are excellent.

[image]

In your Java program connect like this:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8","user","passwd");
```

Comment: I do not have [mysql] group at my my.cnf

Comment: I added [mysql] group also... did not help :(

Comment: What MySQL version and OS do you have?

Comment: mysql-connector-java 5.1.14, mysql server version: 5.1.49

Comment: Great! My settings were from MySQL version 5.0.51.

Comment: mysql won't start if I add these configs

Comment: It depends on the MySQL version you are using. These settings were fine for 5.0.51. There has been a change for later versions. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: thanks :) last option work for me. (change database connection). Hope anyone meets problem should try this option first :)

Comment: **Copy-paste instructions**: Change `utf8` to `utf8mb4` if you want to [support full Unicode](https://stijndewitt.com/2015/06/15/use-mysql-utf8mb4-if-you-want-full-unicode-support/)

Comment: @Stijn de Witt: Fair enough, if you need to store characters beyond the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane.

Comment: In my case it is working correctly with just changing the mysql configuration (v5.7). No need to change jdbc url.

Answer (score 9):

If you get `?????????` add the parameter `characterEncoding=utf-8` instead of `useUnicode=true`. See the following examples.

For english text:

```
String url =  "jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + port + "/DBName?useUnicode=true&...";
```

For text in russian laguage:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + port + "/DBName&characterEncoding=utf-8&...";
```