# character set issue while importing CSV (windows OS)

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to insert data from CSV file into mysql But, I am not able to save languages other than English. It shows '???????' in csv file instead I want to save it as it is in csv file as well as in mysql. Its properly working on ubuntu but creating problem on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup mysql to use UTF-8 character encoding. 
See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405236/jdbc-mysql-utf-8-string-writing-problem)

Also be sure to open your CSV in UTF-8.