# Writing Turkish characters to MySQL using WampServer and Java

Tags: java, mysql, character-encoding, wampserver, turkish

i am having a problem with my Wamp Server. When i execute a query which contains Turkish characters, i am getting this error:

```
SEVERE: Incorrect string value: '\xE7l? ya...' for column 'body' at row 1
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xE7l? ya...' for column 'body' at row 1
```

Here is my Java code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement("SET NAMES utf8");
p.executeUpdate();
PreparedStatement ps = 
        con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO duyurular values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
ps.setInt(1, 0);
ps.setString(2, title);
ps.setString(3, body);
ps.setInt(4, writer);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

My database and table which i am trying to write to are all set to "utf8_turkish_ci" collation. My Wamp Server version is 2.2.

[image: table]

[image: table structure]

I am able to write Turkish characters using PHPMyAdmin sql console but not able to with my Java code. What should i do to get over this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `SQLException` refers that your table/database doesn't support this kind of characters. Please see [here](http://wolfram.kriesing.de/blog/index.php/2007/convert-mysql-db-to-utf8) in order to alter your table to support UTF8 values.

Comment: I googled "incorrect string value" and get lots of relevant looking results.

Comment: @rambo-coder I have also googled the error message and tried a few sugestion but no luck.

Comment: @luiggi-mendoza i am not sure what else ı have to do to support Turkish character set.

Comment: Have you tried inserting in your table by using another tool or maybe the MySQL console?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am able to write Turkish characters using PHPMyAdmin sql console.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405236/jdbc-mysql-utf-8-string-writing-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in here that would tell the driver to encode strings in UTF-8. You are only making the database expect UTF-8, and then the driver encodes your strings in some other encoding and the database throws an error.

You don't show what your `url` is, but it's supposed to be like this:

```
jdbc:mysql:///dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

Then you can remove this:

```
PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement("SET NAMES utf8");
p.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

For others benefit, Check the bellow answer

Add these lines to either my.cnf or my.ini:

```
 [client]
 default-character-set=utf8


[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
default-character-set=utf8
character-set-server=utf8
```

For more details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405236/jdbc-mysql-utf-8-string-writing-problem)