# Problem with diacritic, getting data from database java

Tags: java, mysql, database, string, diacritics

I have MySQL database, where I have saved data and some words have diacritics.

This is my function how to get data from database.

```
public List<RowType> getData(String query){

    List<RowType> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        connect();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

        while(resultSet.next()){
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 1; i <= getCountColumns(resultSet); i++){
                if(i==1) str.append(resultSet.getString(i));
                else str.append("," + resultSet.getString(i));
            }
            list.add(new RowType(str.toString()));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Chyba při získavání údajů z databáze.");
        System.out.println(e);
        Console.print("Chyba při získavání údajů z databáze.");
        Console.print(e.toString());
    }
    finally{
        disconnect();
    }
    return list;
}
```

As parameter i send this query.

```
List<RowType> list = connection.getData("Select id from countries where name = 'Česko'");
```

But it doesn´t find anything, because i have diacritic in the query ("Česko"). I try it without diacritic and it works. So don´t you know how to fix it to work with accents too?

Comment: What is your current mysql connection String?

Comment: Do not concatenate user entered strings into a SQL statement. Use `PreparedStatement` to prevent SQL syntax errors and [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: I used PreparedStatement and it works when i send to query "Cesko" so it find id of "Česko", but when i send to query "Česko" so it find nothing.

Comment: Elliot, what do you mean current mysql connection string?

Comment: @Martin It was [`"jdbc:mysql://localhost/sportdata"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55111501/problem-with-diacritic-getting-data-from-database-java#comment96983828_55113078)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to add a few more queries before executing your main query?
so it will look something like:

```
connect();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

String query2 = "SET NAMES 'utf8'";
statement.execute(query2);

query2 = "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'";
statement.execute(query2);

ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

if the above does not work for you, then maybe there is an issue with your database settings; if that's the case, you can refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5405448/7702001)

Comment: Thank you, the link, which you provided, was helpful. I used following syntax and it works. 

`connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sportdata?characterEncoding=utf-8","root","");`

Comment: I added to my connection "characterEncoding=utf-8" and it.