# Google App Engine - Data being stored in a weird way

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm using Java. This is the pure data that gets inserted in the datastore:

```
<p>Something</p>\n<p>That</p>\n<p> </p>\n<p>Should.</p>\n<p> </p>\n
<p>I have an interesting question.</p>\n<p>Why are you like this?</p>\n
<p> </p>\n<p>Aren't you fine?</p>
```

This is how it gets stored:

```
<p>Something</p> <p>That</p> <p>�</p> <p>Should.</p> <p>�</p> 
<p>I have an interesting question.</p> <p>Why are you like this?</p> 
<p>�</p> <p>Aren't you fine?</p>
```

What's up with the weird symbols? This happens only live, not on my local dev_appserver.

**EDIT**

Here's the code that inserts the data:

```
String content = ""; // this is where the data is stored
try {
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        FileItemStream item = iter.next();
        InputStream stream = item.openStream();

        if(item.isFormField()) {
            String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
            String fieldValue = new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(stream), "utf-8");
            LOG.info("Got a form field: " +fieldName+" with value: "+fieldValue);
            // assigning the value
            if(fieldName.equals("content")) content = fieldValue;
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
} catch (FileUploadException e){
}

...
// insert it in datastore
Recipe recipe = new Recipe(user.getKey(), title, new Text(content), new Text(ingredients), tagsAsStrings);
pm.makePersistent(recipe);
```

It's a `multipart/form-data` form so I have to do that little `item.isFormField()` magic to get the actual content, and construct a String. Maybe that's causing the weird encoding issue? Not sure.

To retrieve the data I simply do:

```
<%=recipe.getContent().getValue()%>
```

Since `content` is of type Text (app engine type) I use the `.getValue()` to get the actual result. I don't think it's an issue with retrieving the data, since I can see the weird characters directly in the online app-engine datastore viewer.

Comment: \n is the indicator for a new line.  Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: It's 99% an encoding issue; how are you dealing with encoding in your code? Can you post some relevant snippet?

Comment: @systempuntoout: I'm not dealing with it. Is there something special I *need* to do?

Comment: How do you know it gets stored like that? Where are you reading that? Datastore viewer or Jsp?

Comment: @systempuntoout: what i'm showing there is directly from the datastore viewer. The JSP just shows a plain question mark symbol.

Comment: @DataNucleus, @systempuntoout: I update the code to show you how I store and retrieve the data.

Comment: But can you see "weird characters" in the retrieved data?

Comment: @Luca are you using the `<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>` in your JSP files?

Comment: @systempuntoout: no I'm not. which jsp should this be in? because as i stated before, it's not a rendering issue since the data is stored that way in the datastore.

Comment: @systempuntoout: added that, same output. Unicode isn't being stored :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed this page to create a Servlet Filter so that all my pages were being encoded in utf8:

[How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps)

After creating the filter, everything works!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using eclipse ?  if yes check under File > Properties > Text File encoding that your file is UTF-8 encoding.

I would guess not.

So, change it to UTF-8 and your issue should get fixed.

regards

didier

Comment: This will only take care of the .java source code encoding, which is a separate issue.