# MySQL UTF8 with Hibernate 3 and Spring

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, utf-8, collation

All my tables in the schema are set to UTF-8 as the default charset, but I can't manage to get Hibernate insert correctly symbols like "é" or "ñ" (they are inserted as "Ã©" or "Ã±").

My configuration is the following:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${db.user}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"></property>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

I've tried adding *?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8* to the connection URL, but with no results... Any idea?

Comment: I wrote an article about this configuration here: http://www.reweb.com.ar/novedades/notas/utf-8-en-tomcat-6-0-spring-3-hibernate3-y-mysql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved, it wasn't an Hibernate problem, Tomcat was not configured to encode incoming requests as UTF-8.

Comment: Concerning the Tomcat configuration you mention, what did you really do? URIEncoding="UTF-8" at server.xml?

Comment: I did that, also I added a org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter to web.xml..

Comment: The answer 4 in this question explains how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding

Answer (score 0):

After adding hibernate encoding it did not work but it worked after adding encoding at page level.

IT worked after adding encoding in jsp page 
I added this in jsp page.