# Why is ñ changing to Ã±?

Tags: java, unicode

I don't understand whenever I save any string that contains ñ it changes to Ã±. Even in the database the ñ is changed to Ã±.

Examples:

- ñ becomes Ã±.
- Niño becomes NiÃ±o.

I don't have any clue what causes this problem or where the problem is coming from. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect it's a database issue, due to "even in the database..."; inspecting the *actual value* inserted would likely confirm/disprove this.

Comment: The database is probably not UTF-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `string` has a wrong encoding. It's `UTF-8` but you need other, uhm Latin-1?
You need decode.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding)

Hope it help you.

Comment: Yes its UTF-8. So you're saying that's where the probelm is coming from?

Answer (score 13):

Character `ñ` (U+00F1) is encoded using UTF-8 as the two bytes `11000011 10110001` (`0xC3 0xB1`).

These two bytes are decoded using ISO 8859-1 as the two characters `Ã±`.

So, you are most likely using UTF-8 to encode the character as bytes, and ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1, as guessed by Sajmon) to decode the bytes as characters.

Comment: May I be curious and ask how you worked out the binary encoding/ which source you used to get it?

Comment: @Philippe: I used the standard definition of UTF-8. Wikipedia has a nice page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

Answer (score 6):

Character encoding problems, for sure. Make sure that the database, the web pages, content charset, java files, string encoding, etc. are all using the exact same encoding - for instance, UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

It is a character encoding issue, you need to check if your whole stack from writer to reader is set to UTF-8.

Check out this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding), it might contain some info to help you: