# Spring add an extra filter

Tags: spring, utf-8, web.xml

I'm having some problems to add utf-8 to my existing project.

I've seen the solution in this post [utf-8 spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding)

But in my web.xml I have spring security filter, so how can I include another filter in my web.xml ?

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I need to include these new lines (to allow utf-8 encoding)

```
<filter>  
  <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
  <init-param>  
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
  </init-param>  
  <init-param>  
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
    <param-value>true</param-value>  
  </init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
  <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem having more than one filter in a `web.xml`. I would simply recommend to put the encoding filter at first.

There is an example with [multiple filters in the documentation of Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html).