# Why this Spring MVC controller returns corrupted UTF-8 String?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, utf-8

I have modified so many places to make my Spring MVC work with UTF-8, including a char filter, contextType in jsp, and fixed MySQL as well, so my project is working perfectly with UTF-8.

However, this newly added function wouldn't get it right

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public @ResponseBody
String uploadFileHandler(
        @RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam("type") String type,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file//, HttpServletResponse response
        ) throws IOException {
//      response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        if (file.isEmpty())
            return "Ｅｍｐｔｙ";
```

As you can see, I have put procudes, and setCharacterEncoding.  The returned String is used in Ajax and I have

```
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.overrideMimeType('text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
```

Here is the beginning of the form in jsp

```
<form name = "myForm" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

But my webpage still shows ????. So what else am I missing? I don't have JQuery, so hoping a solution without using it unless a must.

Comment: The `return "Empty"` line looks funny. Are you sure those are ASCII characters? Maybe they aren't - a cut and paste maybe?

Comment: tomcat or glassfish ?

Comment: @AlvinBunk Empty is UTF-8 not ascii. ｌｏｏｋ　ａｔ　ｔｈｅｓｅ　ｌｅｔｔｅｒｓ．　　Ｉ　ｔｈｉｎｋ　ｉｔ　ｉｓ　ｔｏｍｃａｔ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this link about [ResponseBody](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/74209-responsebody-and-utf-8) problem with return UTF-8 string due to Spring web "bug"

Summary:

1. set `org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter` in web.xml to enforce UTF-8
2. set `<value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>` in spring-servlet.xml
3. `StringHttpMessageConverter` problem eliminated by creating own class

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you've configured your Maven project (if you are even using that) and web.xml, but the answers to the following question helped me in the past:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928162/1034436 - `CharacterEncodingFilter` in `web.xml`
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5933805/1034436 - `project.build.sourceEncoding` in `pom.xml`

Comment: ＠Martin, I definitely haven't put in the maven but did the web.xml.  After I add in maven, it still shows ????.  I will continue to look for it.

Answer (score 0):

Put in config

```
@Bean
public org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter() {
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    return characterEncodingFilter;
}
```

In controller mapping
you can add

`produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"`

but not

`produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8"`

For example: `GetMapping ()` to force `ResponseBody` output encoding UTF-8

```
@GetMapping(value = "/oith/getProcess", produces = "text/plain;charset=utf-8")
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<String> getProcess(@RequestParam(value = "module") BigInteger moduleId) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("any text...", HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```