# How to get some utf-8 characters using hibernate and spring mvc in database?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have developed small server program.
When I extract tuple from database, some characters become ÇÑ±ÛÃàÁ¦.
I modify server.xml. However ÇÑ±ÛÃàÁ¦ characters still appear.
Help me.
How can I get correct characters?

This is my server.xml. (I use apache tomcat 7.0 server.)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 --><Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

      <Context docBase="server" path="/jinggumdari" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:server"/></Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

This is my web.xml.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 
 <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <!-- Processes application requests -->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
  
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
 <filter>
  <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>encoding</param-name>
   <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my servlet-context.xml.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
 <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
  infrastructure -->

 <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
 <annotation-driven />

 <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
  up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
 <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

 <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
  in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
 <beans:bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
  <beans:property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />

  <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
   <beans:map>
    <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html" />
   </beans:map>
  </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

 <context:component-scan base-package="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari" />

 <beans:bean
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

 <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <beans:property name="url"
   value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jinggumdari" />
  <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
  <beans:property name="password" value="mysql1234" />
 </beans:bean>

 <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
 <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
   <beans:list>
    <beans:value>kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.Member</beans:value>
    <beans:value>kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.Festival</beans:value>
    <beans:value>kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.FestivalImage</beans:value>
    <beans:value>kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.Interest</beans:value>
    <beans:value>kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.Review</beans:value>
    <beans:value>kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.ReviewImage</beans:value>
    <beans:value>kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.Search</beans:value>
    <beans:value>kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.RouteInfo</beans:value>
    <beans:value>kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.Route</beans:value>
    <beans:value>kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.Writing</beans:value>
   </beans:list>
  </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
   <beans:props>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </beans:prop>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
   </beans:props>
  </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.hibernate.yourpackage" />
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="memberDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.MemberDAOImpl">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="memberService"
  class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.MemberServiceImpl">
  <beans:property name="memberDAO" ref="memberDAO"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>
 
 <beans:bean id="festivalDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.FestivalDAOImpl">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="festivalService"
  class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.FestivalServiceImpl">
  <beans:property name="festivalDAO" ref="festivalDAO"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>
 
 <beans:bean id="festivalImageDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.FestivalImageDAOImpl">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="festivalImageService"
  class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.FestivalImageServiceImpl">
  <beans:property name="festivalImageDAO" ref="festivalImageDAO"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>
 
 <beans:bean id="interestDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.InterestDAOImpl">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="interestService"
  class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.InterestServiceImpl">
  <beans:property name="interestDAO" ref="interestDAO"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="reviewDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.ReviewDAOImpl">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="reviewService"
  class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.ReviewServiceImpl">
  <beans:property name="reviewDAO" ref="reviewDAO"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>
 
 <beans:bean id="reviewImageDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.ReviewImageDAOImpl">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="reviewImageService"
  class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.ReviewImageServiceImpl">
  <beans:property name="reviewImageDAO" ref="reviewImageDAO"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>
 
 <beans:bean id="routeDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.RouteDAOImpl">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="routeService"
  class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.RouteServiceImpl">
  <beans:property name="routeDAO" ref="routeDAO"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>
 
 <beans:bean id="routeInfoDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.RouteInfoDAOImpl">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="routeInfoService"
  class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.RouteInfoServiceImpl">
  <beans:property name="routeInfoDAO" ref="routeInfoDAO"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>
 
 <beans:bean id="searchDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.SearchDAOImpl">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="searchService"
  class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.SearchServiceImpl">
  <beans:property name="searchDAO" ref="searchDAO"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="writingDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.WritingDAOImpl">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="writingService"
  class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.WritingServiceImpl">
  <beans:property name="writingDAO" ref="writingDAO"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>
 
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

 <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

and what is needed more?

Comment: Which database engine? Make sure your database encoding is UTF-8 as well.

Comment: similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding

Comment: I use MySQL.. In the database, characters are correct. However when I extract data into the spring server, characters are changed.

Comment: And I already apply this answers in my code... at web.xml, pom.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first remove this line

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

and this add into header tag

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
```

then add into web.xml

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

then add to hibernate configuration file into

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
```

Comment: I don't use webpage...
I just use @ResponseBody.
So, I can't add into header.
so, I add your answer in web.xml, servlet-context.xml.
Howerver ÇÑ±ÛÃàÁ¦ characters still appear.
And I use hibernate4.... It change props in version 4?

Comment: it you have not used webpage then no problem but hibernate configuration file into add this code session factory convert object into UTF-8 and insert properly.

Comment: I insert these prop in the configuration file. However there is same problem...<beans:props>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </beans:prop>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</beans:prop>
   </beans:props>

Comment: your table collection change into utf8_general_ci. then check work is ready or not?

Answer (score 0):

append characterEncoding=UTF-8 to database connection string

```
    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table_name?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I found some answer at above answer. Thank you for your favor.