# Spring MVC Form method GET encode Utf-8

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, utf-8, get

I am developing a web in Spring MVC, I have a Form which I want to send Utf-8 characters. I did config and the Form **work perfectly with method POST**, but when I try with method GET, my Utf-8 characters have something wrong, my form sends 'â' and this is what my controller got : 'Ã¢'

I already have encoding-filter in my web.xml and that line in my Jsp:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

So, please let me know what's wrong here.

Comment: What is meaning of 'something wrong'? Could you show us what exactly problem you've met?

Comment: Sorry. I updated my question. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC UTF-8 Encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

The right way to ask the server to send `UTF-8` data is to use a `Accept-Charset: utf-8` request header, not a Content-Type request header.

Comment: I tried to add attribute `accept-charset="UTF-8"` to my `<form:form>` tag  but still got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in your pom.xml file

It tells  Maven in pom.xml file to build the project with the UTF-8 encoding.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
...
</properties>
```

Comment: I tried but nothing changes. UTF-8 encoding already worked perfectly with method POST but wrong with GET.