# Hibernate Spring encode charater set wrong [UTF-8]

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, utf-8, character-encoding

Development environment:

- Spring 4.2x
- Hibernate 4.3.11
- Tomcat 8 server
- MySQL 5.4

Before make the change to Hibernate there was no problem inserting, retrieving and displaying the characters.  However after making the change in my DAO to use Hibernate oddly i can't seem to insert the correct character in to the MySQL DB.

I have made sure that MySQL Schema can indeed save UTF-8 Character set by using query "INSERT INTO `spring_normalize`.`offers` (`text`, `users_username`) VALUES ('ölm', 'lalalal');"  the output on the index.jsp is correct.

I modified my hibernate config

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop><!-- added -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop><!-- added -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop><!-- added -->

            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.caveofprogramming.pring.web.dao</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

This doesn't seem to work

Check list:

1. DB schema is set to utf8 - utf8_unicode_ci.
2. Hibernat config add charSet to UTF-8.
3. jsp page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
   pageEncoding="UTF-8
4. I have also added filter as this post suggested... [Spring MVC UTF-8 Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding)

*** Update ***
this is my bean and DAO

Form

```
<sf:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/docreate" commandName="offer">
    <sf:input type="text" path="id" name="id" readonly="true" />
    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <sf:textarea id="text" name="text" row="3" path="text"></sf:textarea>
    <sf:errors path="text" cssClass="error"></sf:errors>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</sf:form>
```

Offer

```
@Entity
@Table(name="offers")
 public class Offer{
  @Id
  private int id;
  private String text;

  getIn(){}
  .....
}
```

OfferDao

```
public class OfferDao{
   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   public Session currentSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   }

   public boolean create(Offer offer){
     int hiberReturn =(int) currentSession().save(offer);

     return hiberReturn >= 0;
   }
}
```

Anyone who can help is much much appreciated... really.. many many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually accidentally fixed this when I created another smaller web app with just a simple form input.  For those who have the same problem go through the check list above and make sure you have everything.

The most important is to make sure the Character Encoding Filter has to be the first filter on web.xml  reason..... I don't know the reason, so if you do... please leave a comment below

IMPORTANT!!!  First filter on web.xml

```
    <filter>
      <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3):

For Java (JDBC):

```
?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8 in the getConnection() call.
```

For Hikari (perhaps):

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8  
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf-8  
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
```

Spring/Hibernate filter:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8">

Spring/Hibernate: <property name="url"
    value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/miniprojetjee?useUnicode=true
           &connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci
           &characterSetResults=utf8&characterEncoding=utf-8"/>

"Spring": @RequestMapping(value = "/getRegion2",
    produces={"application/json; charset=UTF-8"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

See also: https://docs.jboss.org/exojcr/1.12.13-GA/developer/en-US/html/ch-db-configuration-hibernate.html

Comment: Thank you i did this... but its still not saving the correct characters in to the MySQL

Comment: Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` for some 'incorrect' cell.  This should help in further diagnosis.

Comment: Hummmm i updated my question please take a look... my bean and dao is quite straight forward...  Thanks again

Comment: What does the 'bad' output look like?  Question marks?  Truncated text?  Mojibake?  Other?

Comment: Strange string; it does not match any pattern I know of.  What was the string supposed to be?

Comment: Chinese or Japanese characters.  Thank you very much for helping and looking in to this really appreciated.

Comment: Please show us some specific characters and what they turn into.

Comment: "Double encoding" turns that into `è©¦è©¦`.  Another path gets to `Ã¨Â©Â¦Ã¨Â©Â¦`.  I don't see any way to get to `ææ¯.....`.  Can you provide the hex from the program for `試試`.  Utf8 would be `E8A9A6 E8A9A6`.  I also chased big5, gbk, gbk2312, without success.

Comment: Do you have another example?  Maybe I could get lucky with it.