# Spring Boot - encoding of static resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, encoding, utf-8

I configured a specific folder (`c:\data\cache\<html files>`) to be served statically by Spring Boot like this:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("cache/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:data/cache/");
}
```

These HTML files are being served well. The problem is the encoding. They're properly saved (as `Windows-1252` - downloaded from a website). When I open them directly from disk in browser they're fine. But when Spring Boot serves them, it forces `UTF-8`.

I saw a solution to change that - it works - but it changes the encoding to `UTF-8` for every HTML:

```
@Override
public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer factory) {
    MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
    mappings.add("html", "text/html;charset=windows-1252");
    factory.setMimeMappings(mappings);
}
```

**But then my regular non-static pages gets served as `Windows-1252`**.
So I have to choose one or the other.

Is there any way to tell Spring to serve the static HTML "as is" (or manually specify the encoding)?

Thanks

Comment: You might need to set the encoding for maven in Pom.xml .More over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding

Comment: hmm that seems a global property.. does not seem something to affect my static HTML only apart from my regular dynamic views... but it can work if I force everything to the static encoding Windows-1252, which is not ideal.. but can help. thx