# Spring MVC Rest special characters (ñ, blank spaces, ...)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing an API REST with Spring MVC. The idea to have redirections between controllers. My code looks like:

```
@Controller
public class CustomController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/a", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public String getA(@RequestParam(value="param1", required=true),
        HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
        attributes.addAttribute("param1", param1);
        return "redirect:/b";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/b", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public String getB(@RequestParam(value="param1", required=true),
        HttpServletRequest request) {
        return param1;
    }
}
```

The issue is, if `param1` has for example "`ñ`" character, "`/a`" mapping gets "`ñ`" but when redirecting to "`/b`", arrives encoded character `(%F1)`. Anyway, if I call directly "`/b`" request, gets "`ñ`".

I've tried *https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928162/1722794* without success.

Ideas?