# Content-Disposition filename not being set correctly in Spring Boot 2.7.11

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, utf-8, content-disposition

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.11 and I'm having an issue with the Content-Disposition header not being set correctly when downloading a file with a Japanese filename. Specifically, when I download the file, the filename is being changed to "files.zip" instead of the correct filename.

I've confirmed that the filename is being passed correctly to the writeContentDisposition() method, and I'm setting the Content-Disposition header correctly with the filename parameter encoded as UTF-8.

Here's an example of the header value that I'm passing:

```
attachment; filename="日本語頑張る.zip"; filename*=UTF-8''%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%88%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88.zip
```

This works correctly in Spring Boot 2.6.11, but in Spring Boot 2.7.11, the downloaded file is named "files.zip" instead of the correct filename.

Here's the code that I'm using to set the Content-Disposition header:

```
public static void setContentDisposition(
    HttpServletResponse response, String filename, boolean download) {
        String encodedFilename = UriUtils.encode(filename, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).replaceAll("\\+",
   "%20");
      String disposition = (download ? "attachment" : "inline") +
        "; filename=\"" + filename + "\"" +
        "; filename*=UTF-8''" + encodedFilename;
      response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, disposition);
}
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working in Spring Boot 2.7.11. Can anyone help me figure out what might be causing this issue?

Comment: a) Which browser? b) Are the field values the same for both Spring versions?

Comment: a) I am using chrome browser, b) field values are same for both spring versions....what I observe is if I use the springboot ver 2.6.11, I have a `content-disposition` info on the response....but if I use springboot ver 2.7.11, there is no `content-disposition` info on the response

Comment: additonal info, it only happens that the `content-disposition` is not shown when the filename I used is in Japanese characters....using english characters, there is a `content-disposition` informatiom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem likely is caused by literal non-ASCII characters in the field value, which might cause Spring not to set the value at all.

Remove the "filename" (not "filename*") parameter and try again.

Comment: hi @Julian Reschke, I did your suggestion and it works!!! Thank you!!! Do you know the reason why writing `Content-Disposition` have changed? Because in springboot 2.6.11, it works ok with `filename`....when I upgrade, it doesnt work anymore

Comment: I don't *know*, but I suspect that something now blocks field values considered invalid.

Comment: Also, you can check this answer; it may be used UTF-8 charset in response for file name https://stackoverflow.com/a/53781020/6630210