# Displaying UTF-8 text in a JSP page from a Servlet

Tags: java, jsp

When I try to display German text e.g., Zurücksetzen on a JSP through `request.setAttribute()`, it comes out as `Zur�cksetzen`.

```
request.setAttribute("test", "Zurücksetzen");
```

My JSP page defines contentType as UTF-8:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

and I am displaying the attribute simply with `${test}`.

---

The text is displayed correctly if I forward the request to the JSP page instead of include the JSP

Forward (working): 
`request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Include (not working): 
`request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp").include(request, response);`

---

My IDE is using UTF-8

[image]

Comment: Are your files also saved with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: `Zur�cksetzen` is the result of `ISO-8859-1` data being (or attempted) displayed in `UTF-8`. Are your Java files in UTF-8?

Comment: How do I work out if my Java files are UTF-8? Im on a Macbook using IntelliJ

Comment: Who marked the question down one!?  Reason?

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/ ...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks, checked files and settings are all UTF-8.

Comment: Updated the question to mention that using Forward over Include solves the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question:

As set out in [JSP Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14014/jspnls.htm), the defaults are as follows

```
The default MIME type is text/html for traditional JSP pages; it is text/xml for JSP XML documents.

The default for the page source character encoding (for translation) is ISO-8859-1 (also known as Latin-1) for traditional JSP pages; it is UTF-8 or UTF-16 for JSP XML documents.

The default for the response character encoding is ISO-8859-1 for traditional JSP pages; it is UTF-8 or UTF-16 for JSP XML documents.

The determination of UTF-8 versus UTF-16 is according to "Autodetection of Character Encodings" in the XML specification, at the following location
```

So the `Servlet` and `JSP` pages are by default `ISO-8859-1`.

`request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp").include(request, response);`
When you **`.include`** a JSP page, as above, the page is encoded using the default character encoding (ISO-8859-1). In order to use UTF-8 encoding, you have to set `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` Note: the ContentType directive in the JSP is ignored.

`request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp").forward(request, response);`
When you **`.forward`** to a JSP page, as above, or directly access a JSP page from the browser, the page is encoded using the default character encoding (ISO-8859-1). In order to use UTF-8 encoding, you have to add as the first line of the JSP page `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>`

Answer (score 1):

Set the encoding of the ServletResponse:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: This worked :) . But you probably lost points because of your brief answer (which i loved) . So happy!  Was trying for hours!  Thanks

Comment: @Christian so you're going to write the given line in **every** single piece of your code in the future, because this solved the problem?

Comment: I was going to put it in a BaseServlet that each Servlet extends

Comment: That's a very poor way to "solve" this problem. You don't need to explicitly set the character encoding in the response. That would be horribly tedious.

Comment: So your answer is to make sure every developer on every IDE on every Operating System ensures they save the file as UTF-8 for this to work?

Comment: @Christian that's how it is and why this answer is not really good. Also, what may happen if you change how you write web apps in Java i.e. working with a framework like JSF, Spring MVC or another alternative, do you have to figure out how to add this too on every response from the server side?

Comment: Well I'd expect every developer to use UTF-8 unless they're looking for trouble. The thing is, you might implement this solution, thinking you've fixed everything. However you **will** run into problems with character encoding in the future, and they won't be fixed with this. You don't understand character encodings, and you don't even know if your source files are in UTF8 or not. [Here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) is some reading. You've got a config issue.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This is why I implement an abstract Servlet with settings like this defined which is then implemented from the concrete Servlet.

Comment: @Kayaman, Ive read that but I'm still waiting to read your answer.

Comment: @Christian and that will only work when you use pure Servlets, not when you do a more refined work. Also, you shall not change that response for some servlets e.g. when downloading a file.

Comment: Folks, a) please calm down here (I saw an offensive comment which was deleted after seconds) and b) those who can propose a better solution may post another answer to the question, right? No need for advocacy.

Comment: There are plenty of duplicates for this question. Go through those and see *all the parts* that need to be considered. Character encoding is a lot more complicated than people think, so putting out solutions like this gives the wrong impression about it. Manually setting the response encoding is not a solution, it's a hack.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding) with Spring, the best way is to set the response to UTF-8 globally inside the web.xml using the Spring filter CharacterEncodingFilter :

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```