# Spring mvc encoding and "???" symbols instead of utf-8 symbols in html

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, encoding, utf-8

I'm doing small Spring Mvc project in InteIj idea. Mostly I'm using English so everything works fine. But when I try to use utf-8 (ru) characters on my website, I only get ???? symbols instead of text.

My html pages in IDE encoded to utf-8. Project encoding also set to utf-8. If I use logging or System.out.println ide prints in console utf-8 symbols. But when I send them in a model or just use plain text in html in utf-8 everything becomes ???

Html encoding also set to

I've tried to set filter which will encode all requests and responses to utf-8. Still same ???? symbols.

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <div th:replace="fragments/header :: header-css"></div>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/header :: header"/>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1 align="center" th:text="${text}">
            ру текст (utf-8 ru text)
        </h1>
    </header>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my controller:

```
 @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView showCheckList() {
        String text = "тестовый текст";
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("text",text);
        modelAndView.setViewName("shop/CheckList");    
        return modelAndView;    
    }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding/5933805#5933805

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC UTF-8 Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: i've already tried everything what was suggested in that question. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By seeing your code I can say that you are using thymeleaf as view technology.

Refer [this](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/UTF8-charset-problem-td3608879.html) thread.

Property `characterEncoding` should be explicitly set for `templateResolver` and `ThymeleafViewResolver`:

```
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    ...
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    ...
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    ...
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    ...
</bean>
```

Or using annotation.

```
@Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Do some changes in the database table change character set utf8 and utf8_general_ci show in the below screenshot.
[image]

Comment: my question has nothing to do with DB.

Comment: from where you are fetching data to display on HTML template?