# Linux Not found error for file names with non ASCII characters

Tags: linux, apache, ascii

Simply putted I can't download files that are hosted in my web server if they have special characters in the filename because I get 404.
[image]

If I create a file called olá.txt I don't seem to find the correct URL to download it. I've tried all possible ways to download it:

```
mydomain.com/olá.txt 
mydomain.com/ol%C3%A1.txt
```

and I always get a 404 from Apache Tomcat 7.0.3, but if I change the file name to ola.txt everything is fine.

I've added `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` to the httpd.conf but I still have the issue.

I mean it should be possible to download files with names containing non ascii characters, right?

Update: My `server.xml` has:

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" compressableMimeType="text/javascript,text/css" 
     compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048" connectionTimeout="20000"
     noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, travista" port="8080"
     protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Update:

```
echo -n olá | od -An -tx1 =  6f 6c c3 a1
echo $LANG = en_US.UTF-8
```

locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Please, tell us the output of `echo -n olá | od -An -tx1` , and also of `echo $LANG`

Comment: Also the output of `locale` could be useful, and it would be best if you could do all this as both yourself and the user who runs `tomcat`

Comment: @WalterTross question updated

Comment: If the output you reported is the same for the user running tomcat, then the problem must be within tomcat, and I'm unable to help you :-(

Comment: Try `mydomain.com/ol%E1.txt` instead of `mydomain.com/ol%C3%A1.txt` (or `test%E9.txt` instead of `test%C3%A9.txt`)

Comment: (not that this would be correct - UTF-8 is mandated in percent-encoding - but it would help in sorting out the problem)

Comment: @WalterTross just tried and same 404

Comment: Try `mv olá.txt ol%C3%A1.txt` and then call it "literally" from the browser. If it works, tomcat  is not translating percent-encoded URLs.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add this to the `<connector ... />` tag in your server.xml for Tomcat:

```
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
```

More info:

[How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps)

[utf-8 url problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533379/utf-8-url-problem)

---

I've bee having trouble reproducing this on my end.  I've done a clean install of Tomcat 7.0.26 on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, created `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/testé.txt`, and successfully served that file to my browser at the url `http://localhost:8080/testé.txt`.

This is my connector tag in `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml`:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

I can't say why yours isn't working, at this time, but I can at least confirm that serving UTF-8 encoded files with tomcat7 is possible.

Comment: (question updated) I think it's encoding, I mean at least I have it on the server.xml and the 404 error image gives the utf8 encoded name, right?

Comment: edited answer to respond to the new info in your question.  hopefully this is just a simple typo fix for ya.

Comment: Sorry but the xml had the correct tag it was my mistake pasting here

Comment: Sorry I haven't been able to help you yet.  What linux distro are you running on?  What do you get from `echo $LANG`?  What tool (browser or otherwise) are you using to make the http request?

Comment: the xml code I updated my question with is inside a <Service name="Catalina">, should it be a direct child of the xml element declaration?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might have nothing to do with Tomcat or URL encoding, and it could actually be a problem with **the encoding of the FTP connection** (or whatever you are using to send the files to the remote host).

If they differ, you'd send a file you'd see as "testé", and asking it back from the same source would of course return "testé". But on the file system the file might be encoded differently (*even* if `LANG` is properly set).

Try **creating the file from Tomcat** and requesting it in UTF8 and url-encoded forms. If it works, then try looking at the file name from your FTP client.

Comment: I've actually tested by creating the files through "vi":
vi testé.txt
and I can't download it but if I do:
mv testé.txt teste.txt
it works...do you think the issue might be the same?

Comment: Such test might be inconclusive. You have to create it with Tomcat. Even a simple execution of `touch /full/path/to/testé.txt`, if done by the Tomcat process, could tell us whether this is the case. **I was able to reproduce the same symptoms on my system** but I had to use PuTTY on Windows 7 on the client and a Linux OpenSuSE 13.1 on the server.

Comment: The root user seems to be tomcat user, at least when I do:
ps auxwww | grep -v grep | grep tomcat 
it gives
root 2321 ... Tomcat Servlet Container

Comment: Okay. But can you try and create the file *from the webapp*? That would be a conclusive check, by verifying where the file is created and how it appears named.