# special characters in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get UTF-8 working in java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps)

I have a servlet that receives in the request parameter some special characters. I tried to display them, but I only get question marks instead.

My query string = [http://localhost:8080/specialcharacter/quote/startmilesquote?option=côté](http://localhost:8080/specialcharacter/quote/startmilesquote?option=c%C3%B4t%C3%A9)

I'm displaying

```
request.getQueryString()
result= option=c%C3%B4t%C3%A9
```

and

```
request.getParameter("option")
result=c�t�
```

I put

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

in the servlet
put `<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">` in the header of the reponse.
And my connector in server.xml is defined as UTF-8.

```
   <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" 
              protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"  URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the problem is not in displaying, rather than reading:

- if printing on the console, check if the console has UTF-8 encoding
- if storing in the database, make sure the DB connection is set to UTF-8

(Also, make sure you put the `request.setCharacterEncoding(..)` before you start using the request)