# Setting Java Environment (Apache Tomcat) to encode UTF-8

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, utf-8

I want to know how to set-up the Java Environment to encode in UTF-8. 
Basically I have JSP pages displayed with some Arabic text but they don't seem to be encoding right. 
When I run the pages in the IDE it works fine but on the server where they are host it simple displays it as question marks. I just want to know how to set the java environment or apache tomcat to encode the UTF-8.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: a related post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps

Answer (score 24):

You have a few general settings with different impact levels:

**(1)**  Configure your `JSP` page to display content in utf-8 (place on **top** of jsp page)

```
<%@page pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

**(2)** Set default character encoding to utf-8 ([java system property](http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/source.html))

```
-Dfile.encoding="utf-8"
```

**(3)** Configure your application server to encode request parameters in utf-8 (in [conf/server.xml](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html))

```
<connector .... URIEncoding="utf-8" />
```

**(4)** [Tell browser](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php) content is in utf-8 (place in html `HEAD` section)

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
```

Comment: these steps have been explained in detail in an old post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps

Comment: @Mush, as an argument to starting your server, typically by setting the `JAVA_OPTS="-D..."` variable e.g., in the startup script or as a system variable (`export JAVA_OPTS=".."`).

Comment: any other way to set encoding in primefaces

Answer (score 4):

You must to edit the /config/web.xml
uncomment this filter: **setCharacterEncodingFilter**

```
<!-- A filter that sets character encoding that is used to decode -->
<!-- parameters in a POST request -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<!-- The mapping for the Set Character Encoding Filter -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

In within your project directory:
You must have a folder named 'font' in this foler copy the arabic fonts , this will carry your path to characters on server too....