# Java utf-8 encoding from url

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, urlconnection

I have a problem with some symbols in UTF-8 encoding.
I am reading the index.html from http://wordki.pl to get the list of sets of words with their name.

it looks like this

```
<a href="THE LINK.html">THE NAME</a><span>(20)</span><img src="krecha.png">
```

and when THE NAME has "Ł" it doesent work and puts there "??" but the "??" is not a sign that i can change with replaceAll("str", "str") because my console just doesent show the char hidden behind it.

But when i view the source in chrome/firefox etc it shows "Ł".
And all the other funny signs like "ó, ł, ą, ś" work fine in my program.

So I am asking if there is a way to change the "??" into "Ł" ? I tried encoding it byte by byte but then i lose all the other signs like "ó, ł, ą" etc.

EDIT: Ok i have the problem solved
I needed to save my *.java file as UTF-8 : O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the page **content-type** as **`"UTF-8"`**

Do something like this:

```
request.getCharacterEncoding() = ISO-8859-1 
response.getCharacterEncoding() = UTF-8 
request.getParameter("query") = dÃ©jeuner
```

OR

```
  if(null == request.getCharacterEncoding())       
     request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding); 

  response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");  
  response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Refer this URL for more info:

**[How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps/138950#138950)**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: 1. the website isnt mine
2. it has this line

Comment: added some more info in my answer.

Comment: The problem was that my java file was not in UTF-8 so it coudlnt show a char that is only in utf-8. Thx all