# Servlet character encoding issue with JPA

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding, cdi, wildfly

Ok, I have spent <strike>three</strike> seven hours googling and testing and I give up, I have to ask for help. <strike>I used to develop in Linux and everything was easy, now I use windows and such easy thing like setting correct locale does not work.</strike>

I created simple JSP with form:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<form action="save-user" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

And Servlet:

```
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
```

I receive LeoÅ¡ instead of Leoš. I use WildFly 8.0RC1, Windows 8 czech, firefox.

What I tried already:

1. request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); before reading first
   parameter
2. Filter with request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
3. JVM property -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
4. Remove standard JEE stack jars from war
5. Fix war packaging
6. Split project to WEB and EJB module

When JPA entity / DAO is deployed then diacritics is mangled. If I comment out entity from servlet and remove JPA entity from war (currently remove OAuthLoginEJB.jar from WEB-INF/lib), then I receive correct encoding. If I add this EJB back then it fails again. Is it JBoss / WildFly bug?

I can provide complete sources: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-adlc5KThQDWTdYOEwxOUpTVEU/edit?usp=sharing
It is ready to run, you do not even need to type czech letters, as they are prefilled. Thank you

Comment: Not sure if it's the case, but is your project configured to use UTF-8 in the IDE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391675/utf-8-encoding-a-servlet-form-submission-with-tomcat

Comment: Idea shows that files are UTF8 encoded

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I do not think this is the case. There is single filter and I find interesting, that request.getCharacterEncoding() == null just after request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"). It seems to have no effect. I think that I will deploy it to different container to verify it is not Wildfly bug.

Comment: If you lookup the actual request and response headers what encoding do they show?

Comment: sorry, I do not understand. Which headers? They are plain ascii, so there is no encoding. Or do you expect meta header? There is none.

Comment: I ported this application to current Glassfish and it behaves same way. No JPA deployed - works fine. Add JPA - wrong encoding. What is wrong with JPA!?

Comment: Are you running into [WFLY-2531](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2531)?

Comment: Thanks. I tried a workaround suggested at http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/#3 but it had no effect. :-(

Comment: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-411 - CDI conversation activation conflicts with the Servlet spec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marko from WildFly dev mailing list pointed me to this defect: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-411 and this workaround: http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/#3

When I modified my web.xml, it started to work:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>cz.literak.demo.oauth.servlets.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CDI Conversation Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` before first read from request InputStream. Parameters can be read by the filter before you set encoding in your servlet. May be there is some filter in `OAuthLoginEJB.jar` or in other dependency, which reads parameters first? Typically, this is some parameter for debugging... With Servlet API 3.0, servlets and filters can be registered by annotations, so some filter can be registered despite of empty `web.xml`.

Comment: See source code, it is very primitive application. I just realized during debugging that the request holds filled parsedData attribute already in my filter. I can see some other filter in call stack, I will download sources to see, what it is.