# Java web tomcat encoding filter doesnt work

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, encoding, servlet-filters

Im using intellij idea and tomcat 8 and here is my filter:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/*" }, initParams = {@WebInitParam(name = "encoding", value = "UTF-8", description = "Encoding Param") })
public class EncodingFilter implements Filter {

    private String code;

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        code = filterConfig.getInitParameter("encoding");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String codeRequest = servletRequest.getCharacterEncoding();
        if (code != null && !code.equalsIgnoreCase(codeRequest)) {
            servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding(code);
            servletResponse.setCharacterEncoding(code);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        code = null;
    }
}
```

I dont understand why, but it doesnt work, when I'm putting english words everithing is ok, but when I'm putting russian letters to form, here is how it looks like:

```
String address = request.getParameter(PARAM_NAME_ADDRESS); 
//**address : Ð®Ð·ÐµÑÐ¾Ð²Ð° 12 144**
```

I have this in my jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391675/utf-8-encoding-a-servlet-form-submission-with-tomcat) helped me

Problem was in listener, I removed it

```
@WebListener
public class RequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RequestListener.class);

    @Override
    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent servletRequestEvent) {
        String command = servletRequestEvent.getServletRequest().getParameter("command");
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)servletRequestEvent.getServletRequest();
        LOG.info("Request initialized. Command: " + command + " " + request.getContextPath());
    }

    @Override
    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent servletRequestEvent) {
        String command = servletRequestEvent.getServletRequest().getParameter("command");
        LOG.info("Request destroyed. Command: " + command);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the encoding on the page:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

and also (for completeness) in the form element:

```
<form action="..." accept-charset="UTF-8">
```