# UTF-8 issue in sevlet

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8

While i trying to getting parameter 'تقويمات ESO11 تقويمات 'from jsp to sevlet the value is of the form  'ØªÙÙÙÙØ§Øª ESO '.I set following in servlet code

```
  response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
  response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

and in jsp following settings are made

```
   <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
   <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps

Comment: There also exists a **request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");***. The reference of @axtavt treats unbelievable many aspects too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send this data via HTTP GET you need possibly to adjust the URIEncoding option. If you use apache tomcat you need to configure UTF-8.

see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html

a `server.xml` example:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
   />
```

If this is not your problem a more detailed post can be found here: [How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps)