# utf-8 character set in java project with tomcat server

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat6

stack overflow forum member

I am having developing web application in JAVA. with JDK1.6 version, and Tomcat 6.0 version. and database in mysql 5.1.

I am having country combobox and based on the selection of it my state combobox is filled.

My country combobox is all correctly shown, but after selecting the country India my state combobox is filled but it shows me junk character as shown in image below.
[image: country wise state combobox filled]

I tried to make changes as per the below link specified
[Configuring Tomcat for utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps)

but it didn't work for me.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are all necessary fonts installed on the client?

Comment: @antispam thanks for your reply. I just did the above configuration how did I install the necessary fonts please suggest me some solution for this.

Comment: I was assuming city names are not in latin alphabet. See http://raviratlami1.blogspot.com.es/2006/12/how-to-install-fonts-say-krutidev.html