# UTF-8 encoding in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8

I have a `JSP` page whose page encoding is `ISO-8859-1`. This JSP page there is in a question answer blog. I want to include special characters during Q/A posting.

The problem is JSP is not supporting `UTF-8` encoding even I have changed it from `ISO-8859-1` to `UTF-8`. These characters (`~`,`%`,`&`,`+`) are making problem. When I am posting these character either individually or with the combination of any character it is storinh `null` in the database and when I remove these characters while posting application it is working fine.

Can any one suggest some solution?

Comment: show as the code you receive the data, how you store it to db, how you diplay it from db to jsp

Comment: It is a very long code i can not paste here but i can tell u the flow. User is posting answer for a question from a jsp page(a.jsp). I am taking all the value to a tester.js file (on submit) then these values are going to hidden jsp page then i am calling the java method to post the data. If  a user is posting (&&&&&&&) the value is coming till tester.js file but after sending the value to hidden jsp page all values become null.(only in the case of above describe special character rest is working fine).

Comment: please post the tester.js's method that handles the submission

Answer (score 81):

You should use the **same encoding** on **all layers** of your application to avoid this problem. It is useful to add a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) to set the encoding:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                     ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) throws ServletException {
   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

To only set the encoding on your JSP pages, add this line to them:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Configure your database to use the same char encoding as well.

If you need to convert the encoding of a string see:

- [Encoding conversion in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229015/encoding-conversion-in-java)

I would not recommend to store HTML encoded text in your database. For example, if you need to generate a PDF (or anything other than HTML) you need to convert the HTML encoding first.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more as i am new to this problem.
like where to add filter.

Comment: For detailed information and an example see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info

Answer (score 37):

The full JSP tag should be something like this, mind the pageEncoding too:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Some old browsers mess up with the encoding too. you can use the HTML tag

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Also the file should be recorded in UTF-8 format, if you are using Eclipse left-click on the file->Properties->Check out ->Text file encoding.

Comment: That pageEncoding did it for me. The meta tag alone didn't.

Comment: According to the JSP 2.1 specification page 1-50, if no `pageEncoding` is present the JSP container will use any value present in `contentType`. I interpret this to mean that `contentType="text/html; charset-UTF-8` is sufficient and `pageEncoding="UTF-8"` isallowed but not necessary. And note that either way this simply sets the returned HTTP headers; the `<meta>` tag is for older browsers that ignore the HTTP headers. (The distinction wasn't clear in the original answer.)

Answer (score 20):

I also had an issue displaying charectors like "Ṁ Ů".I added the following to my web.xml.

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

This solved the issue in the pages except header. Tried many ways to solve this and nothing worked in my case. The issue with header was header jsp page is included from another jsp. So gave the encoding to the import and that solved my problem.

```
<c:import url="/Header1.jsp" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this hint. This also was needed and seems to avoid writing the <%@  page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> in every single jsp file (only problem was in my case that this change took effect only after two restarts of the Tomcat and Browser-Cache and not directly...)

Comment: Find the solution without <jsp-config> with Java Config only. Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54835821/5917460)

Answer (score 7):

The default JSP file encoding is specified by JSR315 as [ISO-8859-1](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8aeab80217bbab3c4eea3da462d2e41659c4815a/java/org/apache/jasper/compiler/ParserController.java#L404). This is the encoding that the JSP engine uses to read the JSP file and it is unrelated to the servlet request or response encoding.

If you have non-latin characters in your JSP files, save the JSP file as UTF-8 with BOM or set `pageEncoding` in the beginning of the JSP page:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

---

However, you might want to change the default to UTF-8 globally for all JSP pages. That can be done via `web.xml`:

```xml
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Or, when using **Spring Boot** with an (embedded) Tomcat, via a [`TomcatContextCustomizer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/tomcat/TomcatContextCustomizer.html):

```
@Component
public class JspConfig implements TomcatContextCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(Context context) {
        JspPropertyGroup pg = new JspPropertyGroup();
        pg.addUrlPattern("/*");
        pg.setPageEncoding("UTF-8");
        pg.setTrimWhitespace("true"); // optional, but nice to have
        ArrayList<JspPropertyGroupDescriptor> pgs = new ArrayList<>();
        pgs.add(new JspPropertyGroupDescriptorImpl(pg));
        context.setJspConfigDescriptor(new JspConfigDescriptorImpl(pgs, new ArrayList<TaglibDescriptor>()));
    }
}
```

For JSP to work with Spring Boot, don't forget to include these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And to make a "runnable" .war file, repackage it:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
   . . .
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to make sure the file is been **saved** with UTF-8 encoding.
You can do it with several plain text editors. With Notepad++, i.e., you can choose in the menu `Encoding`-->`Encode in UTF-8`. You can also do it even with Windows' Notepad (`Save As` --> Encoding UTF-8).
If you are using Eclipse, you can set it in the file's Properties.

Also, check if the problem is that you have to **escape** those characters. It wouldn't be strange that were your problem, as one of the characters is `&`.

Answer (score 6):

I used encoding filter which has solved my all encoding problem...

```
 package com.dina.filter;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.Filter;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

    /**
     *
     * @author DINANATH
     */
    public class EncodingFilter implements Filter {

        private String encoding = "utf-8";

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
    //                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                    response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        }

        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
            String encodingParam = filterConfig.getInitParameter("encoding");
            if (encodingParam != null) {
                encoding = encodingParam;
            }
        }

        public void destroy() {
            // nothing todo
        }

    }
```

**in web.xml**

```xml
    <filter>
        <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
        com.dina.filter.EncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a common issue.

one of the easiest way to solve is to check if the special character is reaching inside the action layer and then modifying the special character in the java code.

If you are able to view this character in Action or any other java layer of your choice (Like business layer), just replace the character with corresponding HTML character using the [StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

After doing the escape. use the new string to save to the DB.

Comment: well i got your soloution but i am not able to get the special character in the business layer itself. It is getting lost in the jsp before coming to java class.

Comment: @ShailendraDubey hmmm the date should have been in form and reached the action layer can you double check on that. if it is not coming, can you put some details of the code or some sample code (without including the entire JSP).

Answer (score 5):

This thread can help you:
[Passing request parameters as UTF-8 encoded strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002827/html-forms-and-jsp-problems-with-utf-8-character-encoding)

Basically:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String login = request.getParameter("login");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
```

Or you use javascript on jsp file:

```
var userInput = $("#myInput").val();            
var encodedUserInput = encodeURIComponent(userInput);
$("#hiddenImput").val(encodedUserInput);
```

and after recover on class:

```
String parameter = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("hiddenImput"), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Furthermore, I added the parameter _URIEncoding="UTF-8"_ in tag _<Connector>_ of server.xml (in my case, I using Apache Tomcat)

Comment: This solution is fine, but you could add a global configuration in web.xml by adding a CharacterEncodingFilter, just follow this link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276333](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276333)

Answer (score 4):

This will help you.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

This are special characters in html. Why dont you encode it?
Check it out: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the Hints. Using Tomcat8 I also added a filter like @Jasper de Vries wrote. But in the newer Tomcats nowadays there is a filter already implemented that can be used resp just uncommented in the Tomcat web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
...
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And like all others posted; I added the `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` to the Tomcat Connector in Apache. That also helped.

Important to say, that Eclipse (if you use this) has a copy of its web.xml and overwrites the Tomcat-Settings as it was explained here: [Broken UTF-8 URI Encoding in JSPs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11576094/1856258)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using special characters as delimiters on JSP. When the special characters got posted to the servlet, they all got messed up. I solved the issue by using the following conversion:

```
String str = new String (request.getParameter("string").getBytes ("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Page encoding or anything else do not matter a lot. ISO-8859-1 is a subset of UTF-8, therefore you never have to convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 because ISO-8859-1 is already UTF-8,a subset of UTF-8 but still UTF-8.
Plus, all that do not mean a thing if You have a double encoding somewhere. 
This is my "cure all" recipe for all things encoding and charset related:

```
        String myString = "heartbroken ð";
```

//String is double encoded, fix that first.

```
                myString = new String(myString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                String cleanedText = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(myString);
                byte[] bytes = cleanedText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                String text = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
                CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
                decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
                decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
                CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
                encoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
                encoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
                try {
                    // The new ByteBuffer is ready to be read.
                    ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(text));
                    // The new ByteBuffer is ready to be read.
                    CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(bbuf);
                    String str = cbuf.toString();
                } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
                    logger.error("Error Message if you want to");

                }
```

Answer (score -1):

i add this shell script to convert jsp files from IS

```
#!/bin/sh

###############################################
## this script file must be placed in the parent  
## folder of the to folders "in" and "out"
## in contain the input jsp files
## out will containt the generated jsp files
## 
###############################################

find in/ -name *.jsp | 
    while read line; do 
        outpath=`echo $line | sed -e 's/in/out/'` ;
        parentdir=`echo $outpath | sed -e 's/[^\/]*\.jsp$//'` ;
        mkdir -p $parentdir
        echo $outpath ;
        iconv -t UTF-8 -f ISO-8859-1 -o $outpath $line ;
    done
```