# C with french accent not shown properly in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, character-encoding, weblogic

In JSP page, the name 'ANTHONY PROVENÇAL-DUBÉ' not displayed properly. Letter 'Ç' displayed as 'A‡'.

Please note - WE have four web logic servers and on one server, it is working fine.

Comment: Hi. Use the utf-8-encoding, for me that did the trick. This may help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723339/utf-8-encoding-in-jsp-page]

Comment: Thank you @Daria M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this line. This might help.
    <%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>