# Euro Currency getting Question mark?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, currency

I am using a Servlet and JSP to display a webpage. But whenever I use the Euro currency I get a question mark(?). When I print out in the lgs its fine but when it renders in the HTML it doesn't... Anyone know how to fix?

```
 Currency c  = Currency.getInstance("EUR");
 System.out.println(c.getSymbol());
 String minListPrice =c.getSymbol()+(int)sorteList.get(i).getTicketInfo().getMinListPrice();
```

[image]

Comment: You must read this: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use UTF-8 encoding to avoid this problem.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723339/utf-8-encoding-in-jsp-page) to know how to do it.

---

On JSP:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Server side:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
throws ServletException
{
   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```