# Reading a UTF-8 String from an XMl file in Java in a GWT environment

Tags: java, gwt, utf-8, java.util.scanner

I am reading an XML file using Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8"); and then going line by line using scanner.nextLine().

I have some UTF-8 type text in the XML file that I read and it works perfectly when I run my app locally through the Jetty server in my Eclipse Helios IDE.

However when the app is built and deployed on a tomcat server that we use as out dev server, the UTF-8 characters appear as '?' everywhere. When I put some logs in place I found that the characters were being read that way in spite of me mentioning UTF-8 when I initialize the scanner.

I am unable to understand why it would work locally for me but not when I deploy it on tomcat.

I am sure so many might have come across this before.

Comment: Why are you reading XML line by line instead of getting an XML parser to do it?

Comment: I could try that option but I wanted to find out about this since I already went down this lane. Also, I am interested in finding out why it would work locally for me but not on a remote server.

Comment: My guess is that it's not *really* a UTF-8 file on your remote server. It may have been corrupted along the way.

Comment: It has the standard listed as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> at the beginning.

Comment: That doesn't *really* mean it's UTF-8. Imagine it was corrupted in transfer somehow, e.g. someone saving it as the wrong encoding as a text file, or fetching it via FTP in text mode. The file could say UTF-8 but not actually *be* in UTF-8. If this is the same file you were testing with locally, just the MD5 sum (and length) of both files.

Comment: hmmm... can you elaborate on that? I have no idea about MD5 sum

Comment: Well, find *any* MD5 tool appropriate for the operating systems on your local and remote machines. Do a quick search for one. Run it on the file, and compare the results. It's a simple way of seeing whether they're (almost certainly) the same or not, on a binary basis.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14028/discussion-between-karthik-and-jon-skeet)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have tomcat configured to display utf-8?

Have you configured the page displaying it?
There is a good how to here [How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps)

Also, have you set the default file encoding to utf-8 in catalina.sh?

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

http://www.redleopard.com/2008/12/utf-8-on-tomcat/

I wouldn't expect it to log utf-8 properly without configuring it.

Comment: The page that displays it is an html file and it has been configured to display UTF-8. I still have to look at tomcat and see if it has been configured to handle it at all. Locally my tomcat does.