# Browser showing wrong data

Tags: servlets

I have following code which reads data from text file and prints to browser.
But when it gets data like "abc - abc " then in browser it shows junk characters like " ￢ﾀﾓ"...
What could be the problem ?
fis points to text file. Read data from text file and write to browser.
thnx in advanced.

```
        f = new File(URLDecoder.decode(filePathStr), URLDecoder.decode(fileName));
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        res.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        out = res.getWriter();

        for (int i = fis.read(); i != -1; i = fis.read()) {
            if (i == '\n')
                out.print("</BR>");
            else
                out.write((byte) i);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to output something manually something like

```
out.print("υτφ-8 chars");
```

Do they print correctly? If not take a look at this article [How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps) and make sure you follow the 4 steps on how to display UTF-8 Chars in your webpage.

If they print correctly then the problem lies with the FileInputStream and how you read the file.

You can try the following

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8");
```

**NEW UPDATE**

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        File f = new File("C:\\TEST.TXT");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        InputStreamReader isr  = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        out = response.getWriter();
        for (int i = isr.read(), k = 0; i != -1; i = isr.read(), ++k) {
            if (i == '\n') {
                out.print("</BR>");
            } else {
                out.write(i);
            }
            out.flush();
        }
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

The above code should work fine, i have tested it

Comment: MaVRoSCy : its working (fis and isr) but it also removes hyphen(-) from "abc - abc".. any more solution ??

Comment: MaVRoSCy :                                                          f = new File(URLDecoder.decode(filePathStr), URLDecoder.decode(fileName));       fis = new FileInputStream(f);
isr = new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF-8");
res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
res.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
out = res.getWriter();
for (int i = isr.read(), k = 0; i != -1; i = isr.read(),++k) {
if (i == '\n')
out.print("</BR>");
else
out.write((byte) i);
out.flush();
}

Comment: MaVRoSCy :: where to see answer ??

Comment: it didn't work for me either till the time i removed out.write((byte) i); and set it as the example above. Please make sure that we have identical code

Comment: @nehal if the answer is what you need you can up-vote it and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Your file may not be in UTF-8. I would read all file concatenating all bytes in a array, then create an string with it and then I would print it.