# Why is UTF-8 encoded chars not being displayed correctly on remote machine only

Tags: html, tomcat, utf-8

When I view this webpage which is physically encoded as UTF-8 and has UTF-8 specified as the charset on my PC (using firefox) it does not display characters that need to be encoded with multiple bytes properly such as as the ö in Björk, please click on the link and then open up the B section to see what I mean

http://www.jthink.net/songkong/reports/FixSongsReport00084/FixSongsReport00084_index.html

(The page is hosted on a linux server using jakarta-tomcat)

However the original file displays perfectly okay in Firefox when stored as a file on my harddrive. I even copied the file back from the remote site to my local PC to esure had the same file, and it still displays okay.

So how come it doesn't display ok on the website, could it be a tomcat problem ?

**EDIT**
In the comment on the first answer it says i need to ensure that I need to set the response encoding correctly, how do I do this - the html page is not generated by code tomcat is just serving the page as provided

Note I don't to parse uri parameters as utf8, and I dont want the jsp pages that I created encoded as UTF8, these work fines as ISO-8859-1 and may break if I change them. I just want .html pages to be displayed as UTF8 , and only for this application, I have multiple applications in webapps folder and I am using Tomcat 7

**EDIT**

So as suggested in the answer below I've added to my web.xml file

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncoding</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>html</extension>
  <mime-type>text/html;charset=UTF-8</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

and that sort of works, the url now displays correctly, but the link doesn't work.

When I have a look at the source it seems to be using the correct link, **but the error message shows it as an expanded notation rather than UTF8**.

hers the whole report, so you can click on link in left handside and see result in righthandside

http://www.jthink.net/songkong/reports/FixSongsReport00084/FixSongsReport00084.html

Even if I copy link and paste it doesnt work as the link seems thats get pasted is wrong, although it then corrects itself

Comment: you can set `<meta contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` as if you want to set your .html pages to UTF-8

Comment: I already do that, please see source

Comment: @Mahan: meta tags for HTTP variables are ignored when page is served over `http://` from a real webserver instead of `file://` from local disk file system. Instead, the actual HTTP response headers are been used. Every self respected web developer should know that.

Comment: @BalusC thank your for that.. so as the response encoding header is `ISO-8859-1` changing the encoding in the .html is not really possible

Comment: If you look at the thread I suggested, you can change the ContentType for html files for a specific web application (using the mime-mappings). For jsps, you should declare the encoding in the jsp itself if you want something different than the default value.

Comment: You can also try saving your html files in ISO and they will work, without changing any tomcat config.

Comment: That wont work, as they need to be in UTF-8, as some characters use charcters that cannot be encoded as ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your page is returning this header :

> Content-Type:text/html; charset=**ISO-8859-1**

but your page is encoded in UTF-8.

You can follow this thread to see how to change the response header :

[Tomcat 7.0.35 set HTTP response header Content-Type charset for static HTML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716878/tomcat-7-0-35-set-http-response-header-content-type-charset-for-static-html-file)

**[EDIT]**

The second problem relates to the encoding your server is expecting the urls to be encoded with.

As they will be encoding with utf-8, you can just update your tomcat config with this :

```
<Connector port="<whatever>" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

But what I'd strongly recommend is not to use this kind of characters neither in your urls nor in your html file names. There are more things involved here, as the encoding that is being used by your user when the server starts ..... and many more tweaks you will need to take care about. Just avoiding to use these chars will keep you away of these problems.

**[/EDIT]**

Hope it helps.

Comment: thx, that sort of worked the page displays okay but when I click on a hyperlink it still doesnt work

Comment: That's a different issue. I strongly recommend not to use these "special chars" in your file names. The problem right now has to do with the encoding your server is expecting. I'll update the answer with a solution to this problem.

Comment: I take your point and as the Connector change seems to be global and would effect other web apps running on the same server I canot really chnage it. Unfortunately although I could represent Björk as Bjork easily enough, there is no such ISO-8859-1 representation 坂本真綾. So I suppose I'm going to have to create files with unique numerical based names.

Comment: What I dont understand is why Tomcat isn't setup as UTF8 out of the box

Comment: FYI Insolved the problem by creating the links just using a numericla count, i.e musicbrainz_0001.html, musicbrainz_0002.html ectera