# how do i get utf8 value from querystring using jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am using JSP pages and I am trying to get the UTF-8 value from query string using the statements as below `request.getparameter("q");`

It is working fine, it gives me the appropriate results but when I am trying it using IE9 it gives me `?????` instead of unicode value.

My question is how do I get proper unicode value from query string using JSP that will gives correct values on all browser including IE, and what statements I need to add within JSP page to get correct values at IE as well.

Please help me in this regard.

thank you

Comment: Which server do you use?

Comment: `request.setEncoding("UTF-8");` but in general there are solutions per webserver.

Answer (score 1):

In the jsp page directive you need to set content-type to utf-8 (for each jsp page)

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
```

If still problem persist then use this SO question to handle encoding for DB, Tomcat. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps)

Comment: after adding above code in jsp check if your HTML code contains "<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">"?

Comment: <%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%> <%@page import="java.util.*,java.io.*,java.lang.*,java.io.*,java.sql.*, java.sql.ResultSet, java.lang.String;"%> <!DOCTYPE html> <html DIR="LTR" xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">; <head> <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> </head> <body><%
try{
response.setContentType("text/html");    
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String val =request.getParameter("q");
out.println("val :"+val);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
out.println(ex.getMessage);
}
 %></body></html>