# Request.getparameter discarding special characters from input

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to get some user input value from a text box with special characters. But when I get it string is getting discarded with special character.

Like If i m passing input: poly&&(mer@)
Below code is giving this string as: poly

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String text = (new String(request.getParameter("searchBarField")
                .getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

In my jsp character encoding tag is there. Please suggest.

Comment: Hope this link answer helps you !.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps

Answer (score 3):

I have worked your problem as follows and it works perfectly..

my JSP is **index.jsp**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="GetParameter">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And following my servlet to handle the request.

```
public class GetParameter extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write("Name is " + name);

    }
```

Hope it works with your code....

Comment: I got the answer. actually problem was with my jsp. I was calling action by location.href. When i used post it is working fine. thanks guys for your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @krupa. my problem is solved but not with the solution given by you.

Comment: I had the same problem and for me worked this solution: 
i replaced in my jsp pages "ISO-8859-1" with "UTF-8".
My jsp page declaration looks like this:
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Answer (score 2):

It seems your application server is not configured to support Unicode characters. If you are using Tomcat Container . Set the URIEncoding to `UTF-8` in your connectors.

```
<Server port="8105" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

 <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8180" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" />
    </Engine>
 </Service>
</Server>
```

Set `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` and get the parameter as :

```
String text=request.getParameter("searchBarField");
```

Another way will be to write a `Filter` which handles the character encoding for your web app. Also look into this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps)  .

Comment: I tried this but didnt work. actually problem was with jsp. Not its working fine. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When you send an HTTP request to your server, make sure your URL is encoded first (e.g.: **encodeURIComponent()** in Javascript):

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Server1/endpoint?serialnumber=" + encodeURIComponent(x),
    success: function(data, status){

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

    }
});
```

}

And on the server side, it should already be decoded:

```
String serialnumber = request.getParameter("serialnumber");
```