# Why is UTF8 text displayed as ISO-8859-1 on JSP

Tags: html, jsp, utf-8, character-encoding

When I use UTF-8 characters and submit to a JSP page, the form displays characters in non-UTF8.

String entered in text field in HTML page:

```
εζηθβγδ
```

But it displays as:

```
Î±Î²Î³Î´ÎµÎ¶Î·Î¸
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` tag in your HEAD block to set the entire page to UTF-8.

And if you're wondering, ISO-8859-1 is the default character set for HTML, so if you're not explicitly specifying UTF-8, it defaults to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: I have already added this thing but no result. And then i used the following link. and then it works fine for me. I created CharsetFilter which implements Filter and added mapping for the same in web.xml. Please check the link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/138950/3493471. But yes the above statement is valid for the web application to support utf8.