# Does javascript escape() function support UTF8 characters

Tags: javascript, utf-8

In my existing application javascript escape() function is used to encode a string.

Now, what i want is to support UTF8 characters also. How could i do this.

In brief, I have text field. That, value is encoded and is passed over the network.

For example : escape("Greetings 1") -- prints -- Greetings%201

I followed the below links :

1. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_escape
2. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Now, i want is to support UTF8 characters for this field also.

Any ideas are appreciated. Please help.

Comment: `escape()` is unicode, but these days you should probably be using `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: I used both of them . But it prints Î±Î²Î³Î´ÎµÎ¶Î·Î¸ when passing αβγδεζηθ characters. You can also check this link :  http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/

Comment: Huh, what? `escape("αβγδεζηθ")` gives `"%u03B1%u03B2%u03B3%u03B4%u03B5%u03B6%u03B7%u03B8"`; and `encodeURI("αβγδεζηθ")` gives `"%CE%B1%CE%B2%CE%B3%CE%B4%CE%B5%CE%B6%CE%B7%CE%B8"`. You seem to have some other encoding problems.

Comment: @Bergi try in UTF8 encode,in the link shared. Again i am sharing the link : 
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/ 
Just pass the value in text area corresponding to UTF8 encode. This is what i am getting in my web application, instead of ascented characters.

Comment: @vermaraj: Of course [`utf8_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) will return rubbish when `αβγδεζηθ` already is UTF8. However, you did ask a JavaScript question and not a PHP question???

Comment: @Bergi I Understand but then why it displays Î±Î²Î³Î´ÎµÎ¶Î·Î charactes in web view. Is there any javascript library availlable which support these characters and encode it as well, and display whatever ascented characters i entered in the field.

Comment: No. You don't need a javascript library. You need to fix the file encoding at your server.

Comment: Javascript handles unicode just fine. The problem is with your server code / encoding.

Comment: @Bergi. I have been using JSP, Struts. You mean to say the file encoding to be changed in those files. If yes, then i have already made changes in web.xml (deployment descriptor file) and added a filter, and used the following link to that : http://stackoverflow.com/a/138950/3493471, so that whenever the request is processed to the browser, it is passed through filter and character encoding is set to every page. Even i have seen in firebug, in response headers, the character encoding is text/html; charset=UTF8. I don't know why it is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-standard `escape()` function converts code points > 255 into a 16-bit escape (`%uxxxx`) which is not what you want.

Use `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()` instead.

The information at the W3schools site tend to be questionable at best, and you would be well advised to double check it with other sources.

Comment: At least, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_escape is horrible because it will html-escape javascript code.

Comment: @Bergi: Amazing. I didn't follow that link. I think I'll have to rephrase my sentiment about w3chools.

Comment: Bergi: Actually, it's a sort-of-URL-escape of the HTML output. HTML-escape is entirely different (`&lt;` and so on).

Comment: OK, it seems to do it only for character codes > 255. The `αβγδεζηθ` which OP used as an example will get escaped to `&#945;&#946;&#947;&#948;&#949;&#950;&#951;&#952;` - the latter being invalid in a script of course.